# So much hate on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, behavior

I am a member of Stack Overflow in Portuguese, I cross-posted the exact same question on both sites:

- [What is the most efficient way to implement GroupBy in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20633550/340760)
- Qual é o modo mais eficiente para implementar GroupBy em Javascript?

#### On Stack Overflow

The first thing that happened was a useless comment asking why followed by a suggestion of a full library to use a single method that I asked and this library doesn't even do what I asked.

Another member came and suggested two libraries (which I don't want a full library for a single method) and neither libraries do what I want.

I've being trying to implement and I posted as an answer what I managed. Even though it is not really fast, it works pretty well.

I instantly got a downvote, the person that downvoted didn't even test or tried to understand what I tried for hours.

That is even disrespectful. This is not the first time it happened to me, I tried to ignore them with all my strength. Once I even had to report the comments and a mod cleaned up.

#### On Stack Overflow Portuguese

First comment was a member trying to understand what I wanted to do, he as probably not familiar with C# and Linq.

Second comment was on my answer, a guy told me that what is really making my method slow is the `GetHashCode`.

No one judged me for what I am trying to do, no one tried to make me swallow a nasty library. Everyone so far tried to understand my question and help me out. After all, Stack Overflow is for members to help each other, isn't it?

---

I do not believe that I am the only one who feels this way. Stack Overflow **was not** like this a year ago. What happened? How can we improve the community and stop this hate behavior?

### Updated Aug 2018

This is now being addressed by the [new Code of Conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/proposed-new-code-of-conduct-for-all-stack-exchange-sites)

Thanks everyone in the community that helped me express this feeling and thanks Stack Overflow for creating this code of conduct and new flags.

Disclaimer: I feel like a lot of downvotes were by the lack of empathy. I guess it is really hard to communicate when someone reads what you write in a "binary way".

Also I've never had the intent to make it sound like SO PT is better than SO, if anyone thought that. It's just that SO PT was a new community, fresh, and people were being nice because of it.

Comment: Consider that pt.so and [so] are very different sites - size, community and age. At pt.so you are still **defining** what is on topic and not, whereas at so, things have solidified more - and you get many more drive-by users.

Comment: So 1 single downvote on an answer you've written is "so much hate"?

Comment: And that downvote seems to have been reversed (post has 2 upvotes, 0 downvotes at the moment).

Comment: It's not about the downvote, it is the comments.

Comment: @BrunoLM - Recommending a library constitutes "hate"?

Comment: @Oded The downvote is on his self-answer, not the question.

Comment: What about them? They seem to be trying to understand why you are attempting what you're attempting. And they provide some options you might not have thought of.... where's the negative?

Comment: I agree with some of those comments - in particular those asking for more data. Asking for efficiency without knowing details about the working set and representative data is not good.

Comment: Speaking personally, I'm surprised you didn't get any more downvotes. Your question is non-trivial, and is only a notch away warranting a "plz send teh codez" tag. Plus, someone (you?) down-voted the only answer on some vague performance grounds which weren't clear in the question itself. It's not very welcoming, to say the least. I imagine its author downvoted your own answer as a courtesy for the time he wasted on you.

Comment: Proof of effort is a whole other matter, and in short I am against asking it. You are not giving the code to the OP, you are helping A COMMUNITY WITH THOUSAND OF USERS by answering questions.

Comment: Instead of a war, on pt.so I got an actual good answer. Are you guys sure that we don't have a problem over here? It feels so friendly over there.

Comment: @BrunoLM - The snark issue has been [much discussed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=snark). I don't find the examples in your question particularly compelling evidence of it though. I suspect any difference between the two sites may largely be down to volume. It is easy to get jaded and lose patience when there is a constant stream of crappy questions.

Comment: Concerning the comparison: how big is the Portuguese site? It took some time (i.e. until the site really started to grow large) for the Stack Overflow community to fully comprehend how much damage recommendation question were doing and resolve to put a stop to them. Before that Stack Overflow was pretty easy-going on them.

Comment: It is on private beta. Are you implying that my question is a 'recommendation question'? I really can't see it. So far the only implementation that does the same thing I want is from 'linq.js' and I don't want a whole library for a single function.

Comment: Knowledge has a tendency to puff up. I've found usually the more people know the more arrogant they become. I've found this to be especially true among developers.

Comment: @Denis “I'm surprised you didn't get any more downvotes. Your question is non-trivial” You mean that we should downvote non-trivial questions? This question (even in its original version) is not plzsendtehcodez. It's asking for a way to implement a specific functionality, not a whole application.

Comment: @Gilles: When the original (rather vague) question was posted, the biggest surprise to me was the negative downvote on the only (lengthy) answer, and on dubious grounds at that. It wasn't exactly inviting...

Comment: I totally go with you @BrunoLM ..... To the 30k or more reputation users. When someone try to learn something by asking . either try to help him out or just leave it unanswered . Please don't humiliate by down voting and commenting that the question was unfit . I suggest Downvote should be removed .

Comment: There's a number of problems with this, which I can outline in some feedback. Without wanting to offend you or cause you frustration, I ponder if there is some correlation between the problems inherent in this post and your wider experience of the Stack Overflow platform. It is somewhat defunct in any case, given that you received +8/-2 for the question you originally claimed was poorly received.

Comment: Firstly, it is a real problem to have identified the cause of two downvotes as "hate". Without wanting to state the obvious, you mean "hatred", which is the cause of things like war, racism, fascism, significant outbreaks of deliberate human violence. You fell into a popular online trap, which is that anything you don't like can be attributed to this phenomenon without any proof whatsoever. It renders the other party (the "hater") as automatically suspect, as if they were automatically guilty of a significant example of discrimination.

Comment: In fact, you received two mouse clicks. That's it. At worst, it was feedback to say "I did not like/care for this post and/or I did not think it was suitable/on-topic/well-researched". In _this_ post, you admit to cross-posting the question twice in two communities, within an hour of each other, and each instance of the post does not cross-ref the other, thus two different communities were asked to make the same duplicate effort, without notifying each that their time might be being wasted (because the question could be already answered on the duplicate).

Comment: Then, when you updated _this_ post, you posted an update at the start of it such that the result no longer makes any sense, and readers now have to read the revision history to understand what the original question was. Of course, in order to maintain context for new readers, it makes sense either to (a) add your updates at the end, marking them clearly as updates, or (b) merge your new material into this old question such that new readers do not have to carefully parse the question, while also not invalidating existing answers.

Comment: Finally: your assertion could still be correct, which is that you had an unfair initial experience. However, my _feeling_ is that there is a correlation between the various netiquette issues I have identified and the misunderstandings you have suffered. In other words, as you acquire a better understanding of how to present questions that are in tune with your audience (be crystal clear, don't waste their time, etc) then you'll have an easier ride. I should say, as an addendum, that I do not claim acquiring this collection of knowledge is a trivial thing.

Answer (score 8):

> How can we improve the community and stop this hate behavior?

Unfortunately, I don't think there is something wrong with the community. There for discussing different solutions, challenging the OP or asking for more precision. That's what the users did. Nothing is *useless* there if you are not okay with the comment there ignore them and if you feel they are offensive or really not constructive, flag them.

Stack Overflow or the Portuguese versions are both communities which means you cannot generalize some users behavior and say everybody has a problem. You could have had the same problem on the Portuguese version and a very good response from the English version it all depends on who is answering.

I've read your question and honestly, I don't see anything wrong with that, you don't even have a downvote anymore. I'm sorry you feel annoyed with the comments that were posted but users are allowed to comment about what they want as long as it is constructive and non-offensive.

Comment: I still think there is. If we could see deleted comments I would show you a better example...

Comment: If I had answered the first question on the comments a war would have started. I started to ignore those type of questions.

Comment: @BrunoLM I understand some user can be very annoying with comments but lie I said if it is a problem and you fear creating a comment war, flag the comment and a moderator will come to clean it up.