# Proposed new code of conduct for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, etiquette, help-center, behavior, code-of-conduct

**UPDATE: We've incorporated lots of the feedback below into what we think is a *much* better version than the one we proposed originally. Thanks *a ton* for all the input, and let us know if you like the new version:**

[The NEW new "Be Nice" Policy ("Code of Conduct") — Updated with your feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback)

---

**Original Post:**

We don't spend too much time talking about our code of conduct; the rules are few and fairly straightforward, and most people abide by them, most of the time. But some of these guidelines, while obvious to our core community, are often unknown to or misinterpreted by newcomers.

One of the oldest, most important, and perhaps most misunderstood policy is **Be Nice**, which reads:

> Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you because we’re all here to learn, together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know, and bring your sense of humor.
>
> Please note that expletives are not allowed. If you use expletives on this site, you may be issued a warning or a suspension.

That's a good policy, full of broad philosophical wisdom... But with the strange exception of "expletives", it doesn't do much to help folks understand how to *apply* that wisdom. It focused on what will happen if you violate the rules, but without being exceptionally clear on what "be nice" actually means. It's quite possible to read it as, "So... be myself but don't cuss or I'll get suspended?" - and many have done just that.

To help reduce this confusion, we've rewritten it to better reflect what makes Stack Exchange a far more pleasant community than many others on the Internet. Additionally, we provided some instructions on how to report rare cases of bad behavior; new users aren't always sure how to go about doing that, so we wanted that information to be more readily accessible.

<s>**The expanded guidance lives on its [own help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/code-of-conduct)**, available on every site for easy linking (at `/help/code-of-conduct`).</s>

**The finalized guidance lives on its [own help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)**, available on every site for easy linking (at `/help/be-nice`).

Here's the updated guidance in its entirety:

> ### What is Stack Exchange's code of conduct?
>
> This community has earned a reputation for avoiding ugliness,
>   harassment, and bigotry because people like you have refused to allow
>   it. Please treat others with respect, assume good intentions, and let
>   us know if you see something wrong. This isn't always easy, so we
>   created a non-exhaustive set of principles intended to help all of us
>   communicate well. Here are some specific guidelines to keep in mind:
>
> - **The real-life test:** You shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone *in person,* including a boss or new
>     colleague. Always conduct yourself in a respectful manner.
> - **We're all in this together, so be welcoming and patient.** Remember that everyone here is either generously donating their time
>     to help others, or is trying to learn something or work through a
>     problem. Assume that every question and answer is posted with good
>     intentions. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to
>     treat you because we’re all here to learn, together. Be patient with
>     others who may not know everything you know, and bring your sense of
>     humor.
> - **Focus on the post, not the person.** Keep it professional, and avoid criticism of the author, (as opposed to the post).  Don't make
>     assumptions about a user's identity, and avoid references to
>     demographics unless they are an essential part of the question or
>     answer. Refrain from name-calling and other
>     [ad-hominem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) attacks.
> - **Choose your words carefully.** [Expletives are generally not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites);
>     don't be vulgar. Think before posting an inflammatory remark, even as
>     a joke: if it isn't appropriate at work or home, it is not appropriate
>     here.
> - **Be civil.** Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or
>     religion – and any and all other type of personal attack – is
>     unacceptable. Sexually suggestive language, imagery, and attention are
>     not appropriate for any part of $SiteName, including meta and chat.
>     If you are being harassed, notice that someone else is being harassed, or have any other concerns, please alert the site moderators
>     immediately by [flagging the offending
>     post(s)](/help/flagging). Moderators and/or Stack Exchange staff will investigate
>     the issue and take appropriate action. For the rare case where you
>     think only Stack Exchange staff can handle the situation, [contact us directly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).
>
> In summary, have fun, and be good to each other.

Is there anything we missed that is essential for creating the expectation that Stack Exchange communities are civil and respectful?

Comment: I think it's excellent. It steers clear of too much precision, which invites legalistic rule-gaming, and too much vagueness, which invites honest misinterpretation.

Comment: Will the "be nice" replaced with this?

Comment: Related: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/253.

Comment: Whoa! this exists? 3 years and didn't know. *That* might be a problem in itself.

Comment: Double negative in the first (second?) clause: "shouldn't...wouldn't" `:P`

Comment: Why are "gender" and "gender identity" two separate items in the "Be civil" bullet? On the internet, no one knows your real gender anyways. "Politics" would be a good item to have in that list.

Comment: @JoshCaswell They're there twice because they're technically separate things (one deals with how you self-identify, the other with the gender ascribed to you by others). Politics probably does deserve to be on that list, though, good call.

Comment: This is wonderful. Thank you for the clarity and translation of "common sense" to actionable behaviors.

Comment: So can respond in the same way as I would in “real life” e.g. if 1001 people come to my office demanding answers to daft questions they don’t have the skill level to be able to understand the answer to and have made no effort themselves

Comment: Any chance of extending this code of conduct worldwide?

Comment: Sure, I understand the difference, but then why not include both "race" and "race indentity" in the list? Or "physical disability" and "mental disability"? By including these two subfacets of one facet of personality, you're emphasizing it. Is nuanced gender-based incivility a significant problem on Stack Exchange?

Comment: @Laura facepalm on that edit.... sorry.

Comment: Small tweak suggested: "Remember that everyone here is either generously donating their time to help others, or is trying to learn something or work through a problem." The "either" and "or" are not symmetrically placed given what follows each; they are not both needed any way. "Remember that everyone here is generously donating their time to help others, or trying to learn something or work through a problem."

Comment: Why are 'Expletives not allowed' yet the linked answer has more votes allowing them than disallowing them?

Comment: What is `$SiteName` for in the post? Is that a variable that didn't spell out something?

Comment: @sunk818 Yes, it's a variable. It doesn't render here in the post, but it renders in the help center article so it always says the name of the site you're on.

Comment: would be helpful if this was complemented with a list of expletives

Comment: typo: "and all other types of personal attack" (was missing the "s" on types)

Comment: I suggest administrative wording such as "duplicate of" "closed for" have a warmer tone. The style is emotionally cold.

Comment: Personally, I hate the word "gender" to describe biology. The correct wording has always been "sex". I think "gender identity" is also unnecessary. The common etiquette to address him or her based how the person is dressed. I think "gender identity" can be rolled up into "gender". Is there really an issue with cross dressers or transgendered individuals on SE?

Comment: @Rapptz whaha Stack Exchange and democracy.

Comment: -1 You just took all the fun out of [Politics.SE](http://politics.stackexchange.com/) :P

Comment: This is the most positive and encouraging post I have seen here in a long time.

Comment: Does the current text really cause all that much confusion? And if so, is that really confusion of the sort that would be addressed by the new text? I'm not against introducing it, but if you really need a clear explanation on how not to be an ass, then ... well ...

Comment: One minor thing, since it's already live on all sites, "Proposed" doesn't really fit.

Comment: The more important aspect is that SE is a collection of community-driven sites and so the behavior should be determined (as it already has, via the link that Laura provided) by the community, not unilaterally.

Comment: The main problem I see with any of these efforts is trying to force people to read them, never mind hope that they understand them or care enough to actually abide by them. I know users with six-figure rep that either don't know 90% of that text or refuse to demonstrate that they do.

Comment: I'm not saying don't do them, I just don't want people to have some high expectations that making better FAQ/help content is magically going to fix the site. Newbies are going to continue to be demanding and sensitive, and experienced users are still going to tell them to RTFM.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's live, but these pages are easily editable. Since we're basically just clarifying existing expectations, not creating a new policy from scratch, I figured it'd be okay to put up the version we came up with and tweak it as necessary based on the feedback we receive here.

Comment: @Laura true, but still my first impression was "they are going to change the code of conduct, let's take a look" then I was surprised to see it's already changed. No big deal, just saying.

Comment: FYI name calling is generally not an _ad hominem_ attack - this fallacy is a pet hate! Name calling is only an _ad hominem_ if used in an attempt to prove a point. i.e. "you are stupid therefore this question is stupid and your code is stupid and that's why your program is broken". "You are stupid" on its own is horrid and should be avoided, but it's not an _ad hominem_. Just sayin'!

Comment: @LRiO: Name calling certainly is an ad hominem *attack*.  The distinction you are making is the difference between an attack and an *argument*.

Comment: I hate the fact that we need to be this explicit on what "be nice" actually means. Is there really an underlying problem that we are trying to fix here?

Comment: This may be the best description of "Be nice" that I have seen in a site's rules. I am that guy who writes just as I talk. That is, if you change the period to an explanation point, I sound insulting or demeaning. Fortunately most people here read my posts correctly, so I don't see a problem with this rule change; I actually like it.

Comment: @Laura Gender and gender-identity _are_ two different things. And I think gender is better defined as your physiological gender, not what others ascribe to you.

Comment: A Code of Conduct exists to let the people on the *receiving end* of bad behavior know that the persons moderating the site have their interests in mind. It is not a Thou Shalt Not. It is a "we won't put up with crappy behavior, and we will stop it."

Comment: @djechlin -Very good point. This works. However, most of the discourtesy comes from folks being either overtly, or subtly "snotty," and I don't think any code of conduct will ever prevent that. I would like to add that many of us (like myself) may be senior (i.e. "hiring") managers, and we definitely take note of the way folks behave here (good, as well as bad). For the record, it is quite possible to be horrifically insulting, without using one cuss word. [Here is a classic example from the Bad Old Days](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Warkind) -Sort of NSFW.

Comment: Would be nice to have a magic link for this page, to point overheated users to it in comments. `[conduct]` for example.

Comment: Well, you're missing an "s" in _"all other type *s* of personal attack"_...

Comment: Many programmers would not be affected by the "real life" clause, because they _would_ talk like that in real life :)

Comment: The distinction between "gender" and "gender identity" is not useful and even offensive, suggesting that there's some "objective" gender identification. OTOH, gender and gender *preference* are different things, and that's the distinction one sees in other contexts where such issues are addressed.

Comment: @Minato "... your physiological gender ..." -- You should read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender because you're completely off base here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is correct about *ad hominem* ... see, e.g., http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_hominem#False_positives

Comment: I think requiring people to talk to everyone the way they talk to their boss undermines the credibility and usefulness of these rules and suggests a rather  parochial view ... for many people, being honest with their boss can be extremely dangerous.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The principle of ad hominem describes a kind of argument. There is no such thing as an ad hominem that is not an argument. Name calling aside from an argument is just being a ****. :)

Comment: @JimBalter: I agree with this. If nothing else, the way people talk to their boss varies _hugely_ across the globe so, assuming this rule is intended to reflect some American model of workplace behaviour, it would seem to be uselessly Americentric.

Comment: it would be helpful if people who downvote answers/questions can be made to comment the reason.. as stated "Assume that every question and answer is posted with good intentions", most of the bad questions are there because people are new to stackoverflow..

Comment: @haris: No, bad questions have nothing to do with being new to Stack Overflow. Bad questions are to do with people being new to the concept of (a) reasoning, (b) logic, (c) communication, (d) problem-solving (these are _human_ skills!). Further, this "make downvoters leave a comment" nonsense has been beaten to death on many other threads on meta.

Comment: Obviously, adoption of such rules will lead to a lot of work for mods.  I will be flagging all questions that ask for rehashes of readily-googleable information, parallel-debugging slaves etc. etc. as 'rude and inconsiderate'.

Comment: Like much of the help provided here, this is a write only initiative that most people won't even know exists let alone read. I'm pleased though that someone at SE will get a warm fuzzy feeling for having written it though.

Comment: When I skimmed *This community has earned a reputation for avoiding ugliness, harassment, and bigotry because of people like you have ..."* I didn't notice the word *avoiding*. I'm wondering if it could possibly be better to start with listing positive things about the community instead of listing the absence of negative things. — On the other hand, perhaps I'm the only one who didn't notice thee word *avoiding* at first sight.

Comment: @Laura "not appropriate for any part of Meta Stack Exchange, including meta" -- seems redundant.

Comment: "We're all in this together, so be welcoming and patient." - Please browse the Stack Overflow front page for half a year, filtered by the tags python and Java. If you manage to do so and remain "welcoming and patient" even in the face of total crap questions, I suggest you quit your current occupation and aspire to become the next buddha. Not that I disagree with "don't be an ass", but that sentence feels just like a slap in the face to all of the people who complain about question quality on SO - especially the "everyone here [...] is trying to learn something" part, which is simply untrue.

Comment: @JoshCaswell On the Internet, nobody knows if you're a dog.

Comment: @JimBalter and Lightness re: "talking to your boss"...look more closely. That's just used as an example and is followed up by an impossible-to-interpret "Always conduct yourself in a respectful manner". I don't think that's Americentric at all.

Comment: What is a "boss"? Are we imagined to be working on a chain gang? This word seems wholly incongruous.

Comment: @Yannis - Politics.SE had "fun"?

Comment: @matt - Boss as in "Imagonna stuff your head in cement and dump in East River if you don't show some respect"

Comment: @Laura - "Politics probably does deserve to be on that list, though, good call" - any objections if I edit that in?

Comment: @AaronBertrand In Babylon, the core tenants of the law were on display in the center of every town.  Not every person could read it, or even bothered to every day.  The point is not to have every person memorize the laws, but to have them there, as a reference by which laws are to be enforced.

Comment: @dvk I'm going to make some other edits, too (probably in the morning) – I'll just do one batch of edits, I've got this on my list.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "*the way people talk to their boss varies hugely across the globe*" exactly. Or even without going global for that matter. There's a big difference between the way a banker might talk to their division VP and a welder at the shipyards might talk to their foreman all without leaving the same city limits. One only needs to spend half an hour skimming workplace-SE to see how little use that's likely to be to a considerable number of site users.

Comment: @JimBalter I concede your point ^_^

Comment: In general there needs to be less hostility and condescension towards new or inexperienced users. This site has a reputation for "Google it" type of answers or general bad attitude towards new users who are unfamiliar with the site. So perhaps harsher bans on that would help the site to grow and its users be more encouraged to learn.

Comment: You're in the wrong place, @JGallardo; you're looking for [Why is Stack Overflow so negative of late?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251758) on Meta.SO

Comment: @JoshCaswell No, that was entirely different. There were discussing attitude. I was making a reference to conduct towards new users.

Comment: @Laura "look more closely" -- That's quite rude; I looked plenty close, close enough to know that I'm right about the implications. "That's just used as an example" -- that doesn't refute my assertion *at all*. ... 'and is followed up by an impossible-to-interpret "Always conduct yourself in a respectful manner".' -- so you're championing impossible-to-interpret guidelines? And somehow that negates the language about how you talk to your boss? Yours is the sort of comment that I think should be against the rules.

Comment: @Laura "I don't think that's Americentric at all" -- Perhaps you should *look more closely* at what  Lightness Races in Orbit wrote, as well as the comments about "boss" from matt, DVK, and RobM above. Also note the 15+14 upvotes of our comments ... but I suppose all those people didn't "look more closely" in your mind.

Comment: @JimBalter You're looking for a fight where there isn't one; all I'm saying is that using "talking to your boss" is one example, and the fact that behavior towards one's supervisors varies **does not negate the general principle** of being respectful. I'm sorry if my comment offended you, but it seemed like you were misinterpreting the phrase " including a boss or new colleague" to mean that it's okay to be rude here if you'd be rude to your boss. That's not at all what the text says, so I asked you to re-read it to make sure you hadn't inadvertently skipped a word or two.

Comment: @Laura "You're looking for a fight where there isn't one" -- You're again being rude with this ad hominem. "to mean that it's okay to be rude here if you'd be rude to your boss" -- I suggest that you *look more closely* at what I wrote, as it *did not imply anything of the sort*. I despise intellectual dishonesty, so goodbye ... I won't engage in the fight you're looking to have.

Comment: @JimBalter If it's honesty you're concerned about, then I did a bad job of conveying that the whole point of that paragraph is respect, not necessarily honesty. Does rearranging the sentences of that paragraph alleviate your concerns any? `Always conduct yourself in a respectful manner; you shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, including a boss or new colleague.`

Comment: @JimBalter I still feel like we're talking past each other; I'm not sure if you're afraid that we're instructing users to lie or be dishonest, or if it's something else entirely. Let's [take this to chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/782/be-nice-policy) so I can better understand what your concerns are.

Comment: @Rapptz: *"Why are 'Expletives not allowed' yet the linked answer has more votes allowing them than disallowing them?"* I think you're misinterpreting. The *question* about it has a lot of upvotes. The *answers* saying "no, expletives are not okay" are clearly rather more supported than not.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unless my eyes deceive, the one saying "Yes it's okay sometimes" has more votes than the one saying "No it's never okay".

Comment: @Rapptz Well, the scores are different, but the total upvotes are similar (165 to 162). And a whole bunch of votes, up and down, came just in the past day since I posted this question. At the time the policy was formed, "no" was the accepted answer, and that continues to be our policy. Note that we say *generally* not allowed; we don't go around issuing suspensions for every curse word. If you're cursing at another person, you will certainly be warned and/or suspended, but otherwise, we generally leave it up to the community; if someone flags it, we'll remove it.

Comment: The consensus seems to be: *Less is more* The above is more, so could probably use some pruning.

Comment: @Laura Well, since I've known about that question (i.e. 2 years) the 'Yes sometimes' has always outvoted the 'No, never'. So I don't think the influence this question had was major.

Comment: @Laura *Look more closely* at what I wrote ... it's *your* intellectual dishonesty I last referred to. As for your rearrangement, it displays a complete failure to listen to what others have said, and I doubt now that you're capable of doing better. End of discussion for me.

Comment: Great.  But why not add explicit advice about guiding Newbies? @AaronBertrand and LightnessRacesInOrbit, feel free to read my comment on abarnert's answer.

Comment: While i always agree with the rule, be nice/play nice, because it should always be a fundamental rule of any forum/QnA site, but i can also understand how it is necessary, where people do look over this site for answers and seeing a page full of insults which if later translated if google translate could be the spec for a irf640 MOSFET. But the fact translation had to happen, can make peoples answers look unprofessional, which is the opposite of what this site is about, which is providing professional answers to needed questions

Comment: Then again my opinion dosent really matter, this has already been worked out by admins lol :P

Comment: 1) Minor detail: The first bolded header doesn't work on its own, in the way the other four do. In fact I suspect that the summary of that section would be: *be respectful*, which might then be folder into *be civil*. 2) I also think that the 'choose your words' section might include a reminder that cultural/language/humour differences can also be sources of misunderstanding.

Comment: @Laura - well, since you guys decided to leave out "politics" despite your original opinion that it should be no the list, this CoC is now IMHO basically a joke. I just got banned because a user in chat deliberately posted an offensive joke (knowing it would be offensive to me, as per his own advanced declaration).... and when I flagged it, **I was banned** by a moderator not even on our site for daring to complain.

Comment: @DVK The comments on this thread are not the proper place to discuss your specific scenario. If you want to talk about your chat suspension and feel like it was in error, the best thing to do is to [contact the team](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/contact), though if you really want to you can open a new meta thread about it. A community manager will look into it, but this is not the proper place.

Comment: @Laura - I want to discuss inclusion of "politics" in the explicit list of things you aren't allowed to insult people based on into the formal policy, as was mentioned above in comments. Seems like this thread is the exact place to do it. My suspension is just an actual example of why omitting it turns SE into hostile environment. (and frankly, without the explicit wording in the policy, I don't exactly have grounds for complaint - I'll just be told that I wasn't insulted on the basis of race or sexuality, so suck it up and take the joke)

Answer (score 190):

> Expletives are generally not allowed

I didn't like it before, and I don't like it now. An [expletive](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expletive) is a word that fills space without adding any semantic content (meaning), or that's only for stress. Examples are *on earth* (in "why on earth did…"), *the heck* (in "what the heck is…") and, yes, some other, vulgar things. Expletives *are* (or should be) allowed: you should reword this rule to disallow vulgarities, not expletives.

Comment: Or maybe "profanity" would be clearer.

Comment: "Expletive" is a common polite term for curse word. The top definition for "expletive (noun)" in your link agrees: "A profane, vulgar term, notably a curse or obscene oath." It's not wrong to use the word.

Comment: I was going to complain about the pedantry of this response, but in thinking it over there's no real reason not to modify it to "obscenity in general" or something like that. Avoiding people complaining *seriously* about just this issue is probably worth it.

Comment: "Expletive" has a common meaning (curse word / profanity) and a technical grammatical one (space filler without adding meaning). I don't think it'll really trip anyone up, but "profanity" seems to be clearer so we can use that.

Comment: What about "RTFM"?

Comment: I don't think people would think mistake it as the linguistic "expletive", especially seeing that it is used in the *context* of a rule of conduct. Or perhaps you mean something else?

Comment: @atmelino - Read The Fine/Free/Formidable Manual? what's wrong with that?

Comment: You want posts full of filler words? That is like, OMG, so totally the absolute best-est kind of way to get on point or not rambling type answers and other sort of repsonse like thingies..........  (Have I made the point yet? NO FLUFF EITHER!)

Comment: Okay, then I shall resort to "frell" and similar  ;)

Comment: @atmelino I would argue that RTFM violates _"Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know_", before it violates "no expletives". The equivalent _polite_ way to say it is _"By the way, here's the relevant documentation [link]"_

Comment: @meta.michael: I would avoid making it sound like reading the documentation is an after-thought or optional possibility that the OP may be interested in exploring if they get some free time one day. It should be made clear that reading the documentation is an absolute necessity in our trade, and certainly something that is _expected_ of OPs. We can do that whilst being polite about it, of course, but let's carefully choose our language so that the importance of this act is not lost in translation.

Comment: I would recommend "vulgarity" over "profanity" if we're gonna change it, @Laura - "profanity" has a much, much more restrictive meaning by default, and folks can (and have) argued that their vulgarity, while offensive to others and problematic when it comes to web filters, is not actually profane.

Comment: @Laura: Profanity is already covered by the ban on religious harassment; you almost certainly wanted to ban obscenity or vulgarity here.

Comment: The word "expletive" is more precise than "profanity". While the former has a simple definition, as stated by msh210, the latter is subject to judgement. As expletives are exactly those words which *add no meaning* to a sentence, disallowing them seems a reasonable part of the code of conduct anyway. I see no reason for a change.

Comment: No [Profanity|Obscenity|Vulgarity]?  I would hope there's an exception to this for the ELL site.  Possibly EL&U too for advanced use of expletives.

Comment: Another point why I would prefer vulgarity (or even profanity, although Shog9s remarks are spot on) is language: I think I speak English reasonably well, but I had to look expletives up (for the exact meaning, guessing from context it was quite clear). I think it simply is a not-commonly used word. Vulgarity is quite well-known, also because it is very similar to the latin, french and german (and possibly others) versions of the word. Please keep in mind that many people here speak English as a 2nd language and such language subtleties will be missed by most of them.

Comment: This part should be rewritten or removed. Calling people names should be unacceptable, whether you use profanities or not. OTOH, there's nothing wrong with using these words for emphasis when referring to e.g. a programming language feature.

Comment: "It's not wrong to use the word." -- "Profanity" is clearer, less ambiguous, more accurate, and pretty much **better** in every regard than "expletives", so why rationalize the use of the latter? As for "vulgarity", it's even worse ... completely vague and subjective; just look at the definition: "the state or quality of being vulgar" and  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/vulgar

Comment: "As expletives are exactly those words which add no meaning to a sentence, disallowing them seems a reasonable part of the code of conduct anyway." -- Ah, so, this comment of mine here that I am making should be disallowed? People should be cautious of making what's not allowed depend too much on personality and personal style.

Comment: For non english speakers expletive is maybe just the same as if you talk about quantum holonomy - just a collection of letters.

Comment: @Trilarion: Absolutely! I am not a native speaker of English, but consider my English to be good. But I had no clear idea what "expletive" meant. I would've understood "vulgar", "vulgarity", "cursing", etc. far easier.

Comment: Agree with the people above considering _expletives_ as a jargon I don't understand. These texts need to use simple English, otherwise they are not really useful.

Comment: +1 for **vulgarity**, rather than **expletive** or **profanity**. It's possible to be vulgar without using expletives or profanities - e.g. "I would love to see your melons".

Comment: I super LOVE it.... and fully support it. No more, no less for me..

Comment: Please remember that not everyone is fluent enough in English to understand the euphemism. Please be rigorous and use the words 'curse word' if you mean 'curse word'.

Comment: The usual linguistics term for what is being generally disallowed is "taboo language", but I don't know how much clearer that would be. I'm glad it's only /generally/ disallowed, because I think we need to make some allowance for speakers of other languages (who might not have a good understanding of what is taboo in English). And maybe because in the linguistics and language learners' groups the taboo language might be a valid topic of discussion. There's not much point warning an English language learner to avoid a word if you can't tell them what the word is.

Comment: Regardless of the link between _expletive_ and _profanity_, if we [discourage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=thanks) the use of fillers in other context, such as "Hi!", "Please help!", or "Thanks!", why shouldn't we discourage expletives outright? Are there any examples of expletives improving the usefulness of a post anywhere on a StackExchange site?

Comment: " It's possible to be vulgar without using expletives or profanities" -- Of course it is, but that's no reason to have a blanket ban on "vulgarity", which can be *just about anything* in someone or another's mind.

Comment: @kojiro We only discourage those words in questions, because they are "forever" and not part of a dialog as some new users mistakenly think ... we certainly don't discourage "Thanks!" in comments, and should not. And trying to equate "Thanks!" with profanity is going far afield of the topic here.

Comment: @KPM: "Fuck" and "shit" aren't curses; they don't express a wish that something unpleasant comes upon the object of your attention.  This stands in contrast to "God damn," which is a curse.

Comment: @tmyklebu: Well, that's exactly the kind of subtlety that a non-native speaker has no knowledge of. Anyway, my point wasn't to advocate one specific word over another (I said '__if__ you mean...'), but simply to urge for the use of simple, clear words that are easy to understand to non-native speakers, and certainly do not rely on figures of speech or any other idioms. Even something like 'foul language' may not be clear enough for most non-native users — but at least it's clearer than 'expletives'.

Comment: That would be better indeed.

Comment: All forms of censorship are arbitrarily decided subjectively by those in charge of the censorship. Am I mistaken that in this case it is up to the community to decide? If so, will there be a vote on individual words that the community is not mature enough to glance upon?

Comment: Impressed that nobody has [yet] gone for the obvious meta-jokes this answer nearly begs.

Comment: Rather than trying to be explicit in banning swearing, I'd suggest: "Please don't use language likely to offend. Examples include: Swearing, Racial Epithets, etc.". Most people 'know it when they see it' without needing to define it.

Comment: Just a reminder, that Stack Exchange includes `linguistic` sites (language-specific and general), where so-called "curse words" themselves, their etymology, usage, and translation are strictly on topic.

Comment: Profanity is culture-specific. Anglo-Saxon profanity is not the same as Arabic or French profanity for example. You would need to either abandon the concept of profanity or define it.

Comment: Whatever term you come up with, it technically means something other than the language you're trying to prohibit. **Profanity** and **vulgarity** both mean words used by common people. **Expletives** means words inserted for emphasis rather than content. **Swearing** means making a promise (Biblically: a promise with a loophole). **Cursing** means words used to inflict misfortune. The only technically accurate phrase is "**offensive language**", which is unfortunately reader-dependent.

Comment: civility is crucial, but this is a thought police game. who is to say what is vulgar or profane? i know my ideas differ from my parents, and i'm sure from many of you. you could make a list, but even then you'll have ambiguities, as well as my main point, who are you to say what is profane and vulgar? deep thoughts.

Answer (score 97):

I find the phrase

> Be civil. Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any and all other type of personal attack – is unacceptable.

bothersome - and it feels like it was written by a lawyer. That long list comprises "legally protected characteristics", but it fatally does not include "stupidity" and "laziness". And there is plenty of both on these sites, and there are plenty of people who attack others (incivilly) because of it. By omitting those "unprotected" characteristics, you make the whole rule set feel like it was drawn up by lawyers instead of a community that cares about its members. I recognize that it could be argued that they fall under

> any and all other type of personal attack

but it still feels wrong. I would like to suggest alternative wording:

> Be civil. In your comments and answers, address the issues raised by the question - avoid any type of name calling, harassment or verbal attacks on other community members.

It would be very good to include a sampling of "acceptable" examples of strong language - because it's not clear to me that we need to remove any kind of edge from our language in order to make the site successful. This might usefully make the subject of another Meta post; but it would definitely include

- the right way to say RTFM
- the right way to say "let me google that for you"
- the right way to say "look in your lecture notes"
- the right way to say "did you actually *read* that link you posted"
- the right way to say "as written nobody can answer your question"
- the right way to say "fix your grammar and spelling you lazy so-and-so"
- the right way to say "that doesn't even compile without errors / warnings"
- the right way to say "I can tell English is not your first language[...]"

etc... because all of these opportunities arise frequently, and all of them can easily be written in a way that offends (I did not attempt to write an "approved" version in the above...)

Comment: Practical and to the point. Thank you very much for formulating the list of do's and don'ts.

Comment: I completely agree.  I was going to add another entry to suggest changing "Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any and all other type of personal attack – is unacceptable" to **Attacking or harassing individuals is unacceptable.** to bypass the legalese.  Glad to see someone already suggested it!

Comment: @wallyk - I like your phrasing.

Comment: what does the F in RTFM stand for?

Comment: @CashCow let me google that for you.

Comment: The problem is that the manual is 300 pages long and would take a month to read, and the user has to deliver the solution today, ideally within the next hour.

There are loads of people happy to answer the question for free in exchange of 10 reputation points...

Besides, when I google it, I get hits on stack overflow.

Comment: @CashCow - if you get hits on SO, your question should probably be closed as a duplicate... We need to avoid any SE site becoming a "do my work for me (for free)" site. At least I believe that's how most of us feel. "Ask interesting questions - not ones that you could answer yourself with minimal effort." But let's remain civilized while we say that...

Comment: @Floris If I don't get any hits on SO, unless it's about a brand new technology, the fact that nobody has asked it before in 5 years or whatever means it's unlikely anyone will want to ask it again in the next 5 years, so it's not likely to be of general interest to the public.

Comment: @CashCow - if that's really true then we might as well close shop... of course "hits" is not quite the same thing as "answers", and I think there's some mileage in the old filly yet...

Comment: @Floris Open for questions relating to new technologies and new answers to old questions where the technology has moved on such that there are new ways to solve old problems.

Comment: Your point is taken. The tone and level of detail we were going for was tricky: providing enough examples that it's absolutely clear what constitutes a violation of our code of conduct, but *without* providing a list that seemed exhaustive and would invite people to argue "but [something or other] wasn't included in that list, why'd you suspend me?!" We can probably do better with that sentence, though, so thank you for your input.

Comment: Pointing that "English is not my first language" was really useful. I really suspected it but I wasn't sure. You know, living in a non-english speaking country and family. 

Please replace it with a practical actionable response like "please improve the question" or "This question need to be edited to a more natural English.The original author does not seems to be the right person to do it".

Comment: @CashCow: It stands for "Friendly", of course.

Comment: In addition to the "it looks like it was drawn up by lawyers" concern, I also feel concerned that a list of *specific* personal attacks invites rules-lawyering. E.g., someone could claim that "Well, you're from (country), so of course you wouldn't understand", which is clearly a personal attack, was okay because nationality isn't mentioned in that list. I would greatly prefer not to list *any* specific examples, and just leave it as general, to prevent rules-lawyering like that.

Comment: And a +1 for that list of "the *right* way to say 'please ask a better question'" suggestions. Having some boilerplate that we could copy and paste (and then adjust to the specific question being asked) would save loads of time.

Comment: I think the legalese is important, and I'd very much like it to stay. People think it's "obvious" that characteristic X is protected, but actually which X are obvious can differ from place to place. There are many places on the internet that forbid sexism but permit transphobia, for example. There's no better way to set yourself apart from them than by explicitly stating it.

Comment: In _"I can tell English is not your first language[...]"_-cases, asking people to get help from friends who speak better English is one way to go. That really works well and some actually do that in exchange for a higher chance getting a good answer.

Comment: @BenMillwood - I think the problem with stating "protected characteristics" is that you leave the door open for "well, you didn't say I couldn't ..." for all the things you didn't think of. I think ALL personal characteristics should be included - which leads to "talk about the question, not the questioner" as a guiding principle. See also Laura's and rmunn's comment. But it's good to hear different viewpoints - that is the point of having this discussion in the first place, right? We're all here because we want the communities to be the best they can be.

Comment: Does "be nice" means "be nice at any cost"? For example I don't see anything wrong with _"did you actually read that link you posted"_ or _"that doesn't even compile without errors/warnings"_. They're not offensive and they stress about site rules: first do your own job then ask here in the proper way.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - I did not try to phrase any of these questions in either the "right" or a "wrong" (not nice, offensive) way; I just listed a few common issues that one might have with questions, and that might lead to potentially unpleasant online interactions. I don't think we should be "nice at any cost" if that means "tolerate any amount of abuse of the good faith of other users of the site" - my point was that the proposed new rules of conduct overemphasized (in my opinion) certain aspects of "misbehavior" while missing the point on others; and I suggested some guidance might help.

Comment: +1k if I could.  What is the point in listing protected classes, if you include *and everybody else lol* at the end?  Your suggested replacement is perfect.

Comment: @Floris: remember that a code of conduct not only tells you what *you* can't do, it also tells you what *everyone else* can't do. If a person belongs to groups that are marginalised or victimised, specifically naming those groups is a way of promising to them that if they're attacked, we'll have their back. Not being specific just isn't as strong a promise, because it leaves open the possibility of "oh I didn't mean *you*". Remember also that some of the harm done to marginalised groups is precisely forgetting that they exist, e.g. defaulting to male pronouns and assuming heterosexuality.

Answer (score 95):

I think it's fine, but here are some of my observations.

> You shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, including a boss or a new colleague.

The people who don't need to hear this already understand it, and the people who do need to hear it already think they're doing it right.

> "We're all in this together"
>
> "Focus on the post, not the person."

If you want people to avoid some specific behaviours, then you need to be specific about what those behaviours are.  Those of us who have been here for a while already know what you're talking about in these paragraphs, but the new people don't.  "Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any other types of personal attack – is unacceptable. " -- *That's specific.*

That said, we need to retain the right to say "well, this is how it is, I've made the decision, and that's it," without having to fall back onto legalistic rule structures.  One of the problems with civility is that it's defined differently in different cultures.

> This is offensive to you, but it's not offensive to me.

I avoid this problem during moderation by taking the position that it's worthy of moderator action if it "has become a distraction to the community."

So I think it's probably a good idea to specifically codify those things that fall within the legal realm (i.e. harassment and discrimination), but attempting to explain to folks what "be nice" means, well ... saying "be nice" really ought to be enough, as those folks who don't seem to understand what that means will either figure it out and change their behaviour, or find somewhere else to go.

Comment: This: "*has become a distraction to the community*"; that's the same standard I try to use when determining whether to get involved. (Of course; it's easy for *us* to use that as a standard for ourselves, but, well... back to what you are saying otherwise!)

Comment: +1 for being specific. Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270402/clarify-guidelines-for-flagging-words-or-phrases-we-perceive-to-be-offensive

Comment: Offensive is difficult to define, as it's very subjective. I don't think you can prevent everything that _someone_ might find offensive. Nor should you I think. But I think a notion of intent might be more useful - if I say something crass, then a polite nudge is better.

Comment: @Sobrique: That's why "has it become a distraction" is the metric I use.

Answer (score 42):

I really like the updated guidance, but somehow I also think: Are they really necessary to that extent? I cannot remember I have seen anyone being "harassed" by "*on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion*"... Are there any [IRL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IRL#Initialism) examples of that?

It is not meaning that I don't think rules like that should be part of the overall Stack Overflow code of conduct. Just thinking, one could think there is a real widespread problem about harassing people on Stack Overflow for things like gender. This is not the case, at least as far as I recall what I have seen on Stack Overflow in the past two years and four months.

However, I have two real observations:

1. A non-native English-speaking person can by accident write something that native speaking people find offending. I am not a native English speaking person. It is not always clear to me, before hitting "add comment", for example, how something (like a certain word) can be (mis)understood. So you could add to the code of conduct, that people also (to some degree) should be indulgent if it is clear, that the "offender" was not trying to be evil by purpose.
2. Something I really think is missing is: "**Don't be arrogant**". This is the worst part I have observed actually happening - more skilled people being arrogant to newbies, to the best scaring newcomers away. Be nice to people, even if you think a question is trivial, or an answer is "stupid".

Just my two cents.

Comment: Just a point since your profile indicates you aren't in the US - that wording about harassment you quoted appears to follow similar wording in the ["Equal Employment Opportunity"](http://www.eeoc.gov/laws/statutes/index.cfm) laws in the US. Those even passingly familiar with US employment law will recognise it. As you indicate, it sometimes needs extra explanation for non-US people.

Comment: Yes, it's necessary and has been a real problem in the past, but this isn't a post to talk about the examples. I like your second point about not being arrogant, but I'm willing to bet that nearly no one self-identifies as arrogant, so wording it that way probably isn't helpful. I'll think on it and see if I can come up with a different way to address that.

Comment: @GregHewgill, we have the same thing i Denmark by law. Actually nearly the exact same word by word, even in the same order. It is called §266b or the "bill of racism" (if I translate correct into english) so it is not new to me :) In Denmark any website, or anything expressed on any website, is automatically under that official law. You can be punished by fines or jail. So personally I really dont need an extra explanation, I just wonder why this is nessecary to emphasize for SO, because honestly I havent seen anyone being harrassing other people on SO because of racism, sexuality and so on.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know that same US-civil-rights-movement-era wording was also adopted by other countries too (the [corresponding law for New Zealand](http://www.legislation.govt.nz/act/public/1993/0082/latest/DLM304475.html) is pretty comprehensive). I get your point about it not appearing to apply much to SE sites.

Comment: I strongly suspect you've never seen an instance of harassment on SE *because* when it does happen, the moderators delete it before more than a few people get a chance to see it.  I know I've flagged comments for garden-variety "this argument is not constructive" and had moderators react within minutes.  People do take cues from the behavior of those around them, so the less harassment gets through, the less likely it is to appear in the first place.

Comment: @GregHewgill, I think it is the other way around :) The danish law is highly based on the UN universal human rights, not so much US employment laws :)

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I'm going to quit talking now so I don't embarrass myself further. :)

Comment: @Zack, you are most probably right. Also, I travel around in SO on very few programming tags, have never visited Buddhism and so on. And I guess it is in those areas harrassment takes places. Point taken! There is no reason for programmers what so ever to harrash each other for things like religion, it is all about programming.

Comment: @Laura, a note of arrogancy would be really cool to me. As I now have realized, I only know a small area of the SO / SE family of sites, but this is something I have observed, and annoyed me a little bit. And I think it has become worser, or more frequent, since I started out for 2½ year ago.

Comment: @davidkonrad Um, "Buddhism and so on" is NOT an area where harassment takes place; I'm lol'ing a little at that, but not in disrespect or ridicule of you! Harassment of various sorts has occurred on parts of the larger SE sites, but not much of a religious sort. which is in fact what you meant. I will behave myself, and forego details as Laura sensibly suggested ;O)

Comment: "Don't be arrogant" won't work, for the self awareness reasons others highlight, but something like "try to be sympathetic to those who know less than you," or the like may convey that idea without the pejorative self-selection issue.

Comment: @Jaydles, you could not do better than that? [refering to arrogance]

Comment: @Jaydles What a llame ignorantic answer - you dont know what I mean, you can impossible know, because I'm better than you.

Comment: @davidkonrad, just to be clear: I agree with you that this is a good idea to include, but agree with Laura's point: The wording needs to help people recognize it *in themselves* - no one thinks they're "arrogant", but many well-meaning folks can understand that they sometimes may fail to communicate kindly, etc. (My specific verbiage was just an example.)

Comment: @davidkonrad Lol, a lot [at this (llame ignorantic)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/proposed-new-code-of-conduct-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/240610#comment788551_240607)

Comment: **assume good faith** (*be indulgent if it is clear, that the "offender" was not trying to be evil by purpose*) and **be nice** (*even if you think a question is trivial, or an answer is "stupid"*) are great points

Comment: Your to sense does two make cents. Wait, think I got something mixed up...

Answer (score 35):

Do we really have to call out "don't cuss"—it sounds like a schoolhouse rule for a bunch of kids that don't really understand what being civil means. On the whole lowers whatever code from a positive ensemble designed to promote elevated dialogue into some checkmark set of rules where I feel I could whine "BUT I FOLLOWED EVERYTHING, Y U BAN?!"

Rather than admonishing us salty swine, I'd rather see something like (please note that I am not a wordsmith and you should not use the following)

> **Choose your words carefully.** Stack Exchange (or $SiteName, what is this, PHP?) is used at work and home, by people across the globe. Think before posting an inflammatory remark, even as a joke. Be appropriate and maintain a level of professionalism...yadda yadda.

For those that choose to interpret such a statement as "I do what I want", in practice things would remain basically the same.  The warning could explicitly direct them to the policy post that swearing is strongly discouraged, and excessive use (presumably they've used some already) may carry with it consequences.

Comment: dear me I golly hope this isn't *fricking* PHP ;) That aside this is kinda the exactly same as the previous "be nice" and we know that didn't work as good as originally planned.

Comment: hmmm... isn't dissing php some kind of inflammatory remark? care to stand up to your words? :)

Comment: Can you articulate what utility swearing has such that the current policy is a problem? Note that when it has obvious utility (such as when it's necessary in a relevant quote or somesuch topical use), the current rules do allow it. Beyond that necessary use, what use does swearing have here?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie don't construe this as me advocating for more swearing, I just don't like the "feel" of the "don't cuss" rule for reasons mentioned. The other rules seem to cover it anyways, "shouldn't...wouldn't talk to your boss", "Be civil"

Comment: I think I'm (and possibly others are) unclear on what this answer is pointing to as a problem then. If it's not wanting the rule relaxed, what is the problem with the rule? Its phrasing? Existence? Check-list-ness? I'm suspecting the latter now that you've eliminated "swearing should be allowed" as the intention and I'm looking for other interpretations, but I'm still guessing too much to feel like I understand the post.

Comment: Honestly, I was going to skip over the "expletives aren't allowed" part, but one of my illustrious colleagues said "I cuss at my boss all the time!" so we left it in. ;)

Comment: @Laura, then mention *that*. Calling people names, not using strong words in general.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Defending php is inflammatory, not the other way round. ;)

Comment: @CodesInChaos Which is the problem...

Comment: Is it me, or is "to cuss" [an American term](http://blog.dictionary.com/cussing-swearing-cursing/) for "to curse"/"to swear" and therefor not very well-known outside of America?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel perhaps it is; I was using it intentionally as it (for me at least) evokes a certain schoolyard vibe. Is there a similar term in BrE for swearing that doesn't sound so clinical?

Comment: I think "cussing" falls under "language intended to offend", and think that might be a better metric. That way you cover swear words, lewd terms and racial epithets. (And don't cover inadvertent ones, such as a variable name that happpens to be an expletive in another language).

Comment: @Sobrique Many of the words used and apparently blanket-banned are often not *intended* to offend. Their meaning and level of offensiveness can also vary a lot in different dialects.

Comment: Granted - but I think it's impossible to avoid accidentally offending people, and really - it shouldn't matter too much. That's a very different thing to doing it deliberately. One's a matter of tolerance and education, and the other... well, is just bad behavior on a community site.

Comment: SE is coded in god-like C#, not profane PHP.  +1 for pointing this out.

Comment: I would call you a wordsmith, as long as you didn't include `yadda yadda` in any real document...

Comment: Anyone who says that "fopen()" should be used for file access is a [Insert _non-expletive_ here]

Answer (score 35):

[Assume good faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Assume_good_faith)

> Assuming good faith is a fundamental principle on Wikipedia. It is the assumption that editors' edits and comments are made in good faith. Most people try to help the project, not hurt it. If this were untrue, a project like Wikipedia would be doomed from the beginning. This guideline does not require that editors continue to assume good faith in the presence of obvious evidence to the contrary (vandalism). Assuming good faith does not prohibit discussion and criticism. Rather, editors should not attribute the actions being criticized to malice unless there is specific evidence of malice.

Comment: The second sentence of the new page says, "Please treat others with respect, **assume good intentions**, and let us know if you see something wrong." (bolded here for emphasis) The fact that you missed it means maybe we should call more attention to it, though :)

Comment: I edit Wikipedia, but we aren't Wikipedia. @Laura I think it would be a good idea to call more attention to the "assume good intentions" portion here. I missed it!

Comment: Yes, I see now! I think this should be a separate bolded point.

Comment: @Laura For what it's worth, I thought "**Assume good faith**" is more to the point than "**We're all in this together, so be welcoming and patient**"

Comment: And while we're at it, quote [Hanlon's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor).

Comment: I think "assume good faith" is the wrong standard here. Most questions, especially by new users, are blatantly help-vampire questions. Assuming they were intended to be good questions is a bad idea. Assuming that most users either would (try to) write good questions or go away if they understood the system is a good idea. But that's not the same as the Wikipedia standard; there, you're supposed to assume that the editor understands the point of Wikipedia and is trying to act accordingly, while here we're better assuming they _don't_ get the point, and that's why they've written a bad question.

Comment: @abarnert I agree that "assume good faith" (AGF) should not be used here in the way you would use it on Wikipedia w.r.t. newcomers; this site is different from Wikipedia. AGF should be in general be taken as a general attitude of tolerance toward criticism, it is helpful when there is a potential for disputes due to criticisms of the conduct of users. In practice AGF in case of dealing with students would mean that students who seek help with homework here would be asked to be a tolerant w.r.t. criticism about showing effort.

Answer (score 27):

The "Be civil" section isn't really about civility.

Civility is courtesy and politeness, contrasted with rude or aggressive behavior. Most of that stuff is actually covered by the "Focus on the post, not the person" section.

As written right now, the "Be civil" section is more about something else: outright hate and hostility that transcend mere incivility. I think another label would be better — partly because I think this is a *bigger* deal than merely being civil; partly because I think your **community standards should stress that merely adopting the veneer of civility isn't enough to make harassment or group attacks acceptable on the site**.

(I like that section overall. It's very important. But putting "Be civil" in front of it obscures the true meaning of that paragraph.)

Comment: A hearty "right on!" to "...should stress that merely adopting the veneer of civility isn't enough to make harassment or group attacks acceptable on the site."

Comment: I'm curious how you think the language can be modified to stress that adopting a veneer of civility only doesn't cut it. I thought the language was pretty clear that harassment and other disrespectful behavior was off-limits, but if that's not coming across, I'm open to suggestion for how to make it more obvious.

Comment: @Laura Just the section title. It's not really "Be civil," it's... I don't know what a concise alternative would be. "Respect," probably. Gonna ask around for some more options. Again, just the title -- I like the rest of that section text just as it is already!

Answer (score 26):

I'm a fan of the older version, and I will certainly *miss* it. This feels clunky in comparison. It's wordy, not very readable.

It's simple - It doesn't look like it was written by a lawyer. It put across something that really is a *simple* concept. It treats people like adults, and leaves room for the community to interpret it. It sums up things fairly succinctly. It makes a much more *natural* way to start things off - even if you go in detail.

> Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.
>   Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you
>   because we’re all here to learn, together. Be tolerant of others who
>   may not know everything you know, and bring your sense of humor.

may be a nice way to start the new code of conduct, and a nod to what we've used for years.

Other issues I have with the newer version would probably be fixed with a little bit of compression, I suspect

For example,

> Be civil. Attacking or harassing individuals <strike>based on gender,
>   sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or
>   religion – –</strike> and any and all other type of personal attack 
>   *for any reason* is unacceptable.

This is *much* more inclusive, without sounding like its written by a politically correct committee. I can think of other sorts of incivility that could occur on a tech centric site.

> If you are being harassed, notice that someone else is being harassed,
>   or have any other concerns, please alert the site moderators
>   immediately by flagging the offending post(s). Moderators and/or Stack
>   Exchange staff will investigate the issue and take appropriate action.
>   For the rare case where you think only Stack Exchange staff can handle
>   the situation, contact us directly.
>    feels like it has better flow
>
> Sexually suggestive language, imagery, and attention are not
>   appropriate for any part of $SiteName, including meta and chat.

On the other hand may fit in better under the bit about language - since it deals with language use.

> Choose your words carefully - what you say reflects on the site and
>   yourself. Expletives are generally not allowed; <strike>don't be
>   vulgar</strike> Think before posting an inflammatory remark, even as a
>   joke and sexually suggestive language, imagery, and attention are not
>   appropriate for any part of $SiteName, including meta and chat: if it
>   isn't appropriate at work or home, it is not appropriate here.
>   Bit of repetition there, since you're talking about the same things

Comment: This doesn't need to be readable as no one will bother once this question disappears from the front page.

Answer (score 24):

> The real-life test: You shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, including a boss or new colleague.

I think "including a boss" here makes this too broad. I might comment a bad question on an SE site with, "This question is ill-posed. You might like to read [some wikipedia page] to understand the terms you're using, and then come back and edit your question." I might even say something broadly similar to a new colleague if they're saying stupid things. I wouldn't say that to a boss or a customer. Is it really your intent to outlaw a helpful and neutral, if curt, moderation comment as "not nice"?

I try to help poor questions or answerers by suggesting how they might improve their post. If I were restricted to only things I would say to my boss, a lot of those close- or down-votes would become silent, simply because there are things you can't say to a boss, however politely.

> Remember that everyone here is either generously donating their time to help others, or is trying to learn something or work through a problem. Assume that every question and answer is posted with good intentions.

This is usually but not always true. Assuming good faith is usually a good idea, but we do get visitors who spam the site or post inflammatory and/or offensive rants simply because they're frustrated with life. If **everyone** on every SE site were trying to help others or solve a problem, we wouldn't have spam flags and the other moderation tools, or even a guide to "being nice".

I can agree with the sentiment behind this suggestion. For example, when the same user repeatedly posts the very same question, I don't get aggrieved and tell them they're a bad person for wilfully posting duplicates; instead, I explain that it's counter-productive on SE sites, and how to edit a question to add more information. But the absolutism of "everyone here" and "every question and answer" are demonstrably false. A rule that's overtly based on false premises disrespects the people who are supposed to follow it, and will never be respected or followed. This statement needs to be weakened with an "in general", or a complete rewording, in order to be any use.

Answer (score 23):

Could I suggest that for the religion sites (Biblical Hermeneutics.SE, Buddhism.SE, Christianity.SE, Islam.SE, Judaism.SE, and the like), this language is going to cause confusion or consternation:

> Be civil. Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any and all other types of personal attack – is unacceptable.

I know there is going to come a point when someone who simply disagrees with something somebody has written is going to say "The mods are suppressing me." Islam.SE has its Sunni-Shia problems, Christianity.SE has its users who particularly "oppressed" and it is very easy to get one's nose out of joint.  Furthermore, we are all sick of jabs that some people want to take in the guise of a question or answer, no matter how disingenuous.

At our best, the religion sites work very hard to remind everyone that we are secular (even if most of the members are believers) and that we are actually NOT interested in debate.  On Christianity.SE, in particular, we regularly tell users that we are [different from other sites](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808).

Even with all of that, users will feel oppressed. They will feel their ideas are being singled out and attacked. For our religious sites, in particular, this language may be helpful:

> Please note that Stack Exchange seeks neither to promote nor discourage any viewpoint. On religious sites, in particular, we do not wish to encourage ongoing arguments amongst religions or within sects thereof.
>
> Questions and Answers should be neutral in tone, supported with historical and verifiable resources, and not used for proselytization or denigration. Evaluating the merits of ideas or behaviours within documented established traditions of the scope of a given site is not an attack. Demonstrating that a particular argument is outside the expressed tradition of the site is not suppression or oppression. Without exception, Stack Exchange religion sites seek to be academic resources and conform to norms of behaviour one would find within the academic environment that studies them.
>
> If your professor would call you out for a statement, it is out of bounds.

Comment: Religions themselves often have a clear opinion about gender, sexual orientation, etc.. However, this does not allow posters to attack each other on these basis.

Comment: That is exactly what I am saying. Be neutral and support. Explain don't attack. But don't lie either.  If a religion is against a behavior, don't try to say it is.

Comment: The "If your professor would call you out" is a great test.  Saying "The book of Romans calls homosexuality a sin" is a very different statement than "<Insert derogatory term here> deserve hell."

Comment: @AffableGeek You meant "If a religion is against a behavior, don't try to say it is not", yes?

Comment: You are correct @EllieKesselman.  :)

Comment: But who professes the professors?

Comment: As you know, [this is nothing new](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/713/is-this-hate-speech) - folks have tried to use such reasoning to censor posts they disagreed with in the past, and no doubt will in the future. And the solution - as again, you know well - is to fix the *questions*. You've probably seen this too, but there's [a relevant discussion on Meta History Stack Exchange](http://meta.history.stackexchange.com/questions/504/how-should-we-deal-with-sensitive-historical-questions)...

Comment: "Religious" sites on SE will always be a problem. I'm a Christian, and I've been on CSE... I no longer visit (for probably well over a year(?) now). Why? Because it is an open platform for people to poke fun at us and then pretend to get mad if we don't play into their little game. It's basically a "skeptics" (pff... yeah right) site by a different name.

Comment: "Be civil. Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any and all other type of personal attack – is unacceptable. " -- This should be **especially** emphasized on religious sites. Fundamentally hostile ideas and attitudes should not be encouraged.

Comment: "Because it is an open platform for people to poke fun at us and then pretend to get mad if we don't play into their little game." -- It's called being honest. No belief is immune from criticism, and no demand that criticisms are to be banned should be honored. *"skeptics" (pff... yeah right)* -- Now **that** is the sort of ad hominem comment that should be banned.

Comment: *No belief is immune from criticism* -- of course not. But a couple of christians should be able to discuss christianity without feeling under constant attack or demands to justify their beliefs by atheists or people of other beliefs, and vice-versa. If that's impossible on those sites (and I don't know, I don't have a dog in this fight) then that seems wrong to me.

Comment: @AffableGeek - the problem is that a large segment of US population sees absolutely NO difference between these 2 statements: "The book of Romans calls homosexuality a sin" is a very different statement than "<Insert derogatory term here> deserve hell." - and that includes BOTH religious bigots and left-wing bigots alike in terms of not seeing the distinction.

Comment: "*If your professor would call you out*" isn't a useful guideline for people who don't have a professor, or who have only interacted with professors who are disinclined to duel.

Comment: I would suggest that religion sites could work out their own policies, which would be in addition to the network-wide code of conduct.  If they adopt your proposed language, great!  I'm not sure it's a good idea to add stuff to the network-wide code of conduct that is only relevant to religion sites.  Nothing says that the network-wide code of conduct is the end of the story.

Comment: I don't think the expanded version is particularly useful even if limited to the religious sites: it's basically just a "This is how the vague and general civility rules *particularly* apply to *this* particular site" boilerplate which is probably better off not being a boilerplate at all, rather it should be hashed out in each site's respective metas.

Comment: I do agree that the "Attacking or harassing individuals..." wording needs some tweaking though, as often (especially on religious sites) harassment is done at a higher level of abstraction: "So-and-so is a liar and deserves to burn in hell" is far less common than "Unnamed followers of such-and-such [including but hardly limited to the person who is personally arguing with me right now] are liars and deserve to burn in hell", but no less problematic.

Comment: This religious sites’ example shows *why* certain sites can’t become “academic resources” in the same sense as sites about sciences. Religion controls people, whereas sciences study the nature; this difference in motivation of actors is fundamental. Behavioural restrictions necessary to contain “holy hatred” in religious context (and hence preserve civil peace) serve to nothing applied to feuds between scientific theories.

Doesn’t it demonstrate that a grand unified code of conduct for all sites is not a very good idea?

Answer (score 19):

Two minor typographic issues.  Normally, I'd just edit the post to fix them, but it isn't clear that will work as desired here.

> Keep it professional, and avoid criticism of the author, (as opposed to the post).

If you removed the parenthetical, you would be left with a comma followed by a full stop (period).  The comma is therefore unnecessary — the brackets (parentheses) already serve to separate the comment from the preceding text.

The second is potentially more debatable:

> – and any and all other type of personal attack –

I'd use 'types' in place of 'type', but you can argue for the singular.  If it were "and all other type of personal attack", I think the singular would be wrong.  If it were "and any other type of personal attack", the singular is OK, but "and any other types of personal attack" would also be OK.  So, on balance I suggest it should be "and any and all other types of personal attack", but I won't be heartbroken if the change is not made (even though it will grate mildly on me every time I read it).

---

#### Tweaking the second issue

Looking at the second issue in the larger context, the suggested revision would leave a problem with agreement (of verb and noun) in the use of 'is' versus 'are'.  Italics mark changes rather than emphasis.

Original:

> Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any and all other type of personal attack – is unacceptable.

First suggested revision:

> Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any and all other *types* of personal attack – is unacceptable.

The 'is' is correct for the non-parenthetical statement; 'are' should replace 'is' for the parenthetical comment.  This is a problem.

I suggest a slightly bigger rewording to keep the intent but fix the grammatical agreement:

> Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion *is unacceptable – and so are* any and all other types of personal attack.

Or even, using a more active voice:

> *You may not attack or harass* individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion. *Any* and all other types of personal attack *are also unacceptable*.

Comment: Thanks for the copy edit; I'll incorporate it into the larger update I'm doing based on other feedback here.

Comment: **Excellent** copy edits.

Answer (score 19):

I remember some Internet celebrity developer, Joel *something or other*, the name escapes me right now, pointing out that [people don't read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html).

If they're not reading the shorter guidelines we have now, why are we expecting them to read longer ones?

Statements like this always tends to be overwrought and overdone, and I can see that happening here. We really *should* be able to say "Treat others with *at least* as much respect as you would like to be given yourself. That means no bigotry, no bullying, no stalking, no trolling, no rudeness. By all means disagree with something if you need to but attack the ideas, not the person. If you don't behave you will get your ass bounced out the door. Discussion over thanks for coming"

I don't believe this proposal will improve things:

1. The people who aren't reading the current guidelines still won't read them.
2. The people who consider themselves to be special snowflakes will continue to do so.
3. Overly-complex statements are open season for rules-lawyering jerks to whinge once they get banned.

Comment: On the meta of a site I'm active on, some questions have come up about conduct in recent months. Having a more expanded Code of Conduct would actually be really helpful in circumstances like that. (And not because of terrible circumstances either; it's just come up as relevant to certain events, and the discourse has been mostly respectful.)

Comment: @doppelgreener I'm not against the idea of improving the CoC *per se*, I just don't see the mealy-mouthed attempt in the question as an improvement. I think that the attempt to over-clarify certain terms in that example ultimately *weakens* the message. That's my objection. I'm only advocating that the CoC should be as short and to the point as possible because I think that usually achieves the best result, not because I'm personally allergic to reading...

Comment: I completely agree with you that some people just won't read regardless of how much or little information there is for them to consume. With the expanded code of conduct, though, experienced users can direct other people to a page *specifically dealing with our expectations for behavior*; those who care about the community can read it and those who don't will at least be unable to say they didn't know they were violating a rule.

Comment: I love the short version you've posted. People don't read, but the subset who do, tend to only read short things. So give them a short thing to read that captures the essence. You've done that beautifully.

Comment: This is what I was going to say, only far more succinctly than I would have said it. :-) When a code of conduct turns into a list of specific rules, it tends to invite rules-lawyering. "But it didn't say I couldn't do X," when X was clearly rude, harassing behavior (which someone had forgotten to include in the specific rules). MUCH better to keep it simple.

Answer (score 18):

> You shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, including **a boss** or new colleague.

For the love of all that is pure and true, please delete "a boss".

We want folks to tell the truth and to be frank and to the point.

We don't want folks self-censoring or window-dressing like we do when we talk to people who have more or less arbitrary power over our livelihoods.

Plain "colleagues" is just fine.

Comment: Answering questions on SE, like a boss.

Answer (score 17):

### Drop that *boss*, I am a volunteer

Word like ["boss"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boss), "client", "customer" is not appropriate when targeting [*volunteer*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voluntarily) audience. Stack Exchange users contribute freely, in their free time, at their own terms and you shouldn't expect them to treat others like a boss.

Now, don't get me wrong, I find "talking like to a boss" fantastically efficient approach. I've seen it used frequently in comments at [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) and it's... wonderful. Ruthless analysis of what's wrong with the post, packed into explicitly friendly message<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269461/839601)</sup> looks and works great, even (especially!) when used against very low quality, heavily downvoted posts.

I am trying to learn this way myself and wouldn't hesitate to *personally* recommend it to anyone. But no matter how I like it, it simply has no place in a general guidance for volunteer users.

<sub>PS. Wonder if this was introduced as a ["duck feature"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/168147/31260).</sub>

Comment: I think almost everyone, whether they have a job with a boss (or colleagues) or not, would understand what is meant there. The phrasing doesn't imply you *have* a boss or colleagues. I don't see what the problem is here.

Comment: @Duncan [boss](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boss) is a "person who exercises control or authority"; one I'd take an _extra_ effort to avoid coming up as confrontational when delivering negative message. I learned (rather hard way) to properly talk to boss at my paid jobs and I am learning to do so here (as this seems to be efficient approach). And I believe this is not appropriate in a guidance targeted at users who contribute [voluntarily](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/voluntarily), that is because they want to and not because they are forced to

Comment: Ah, I understand. So your complaint is not about the choice of words being offensive, but rather that we don't need to be *that* polite to people we are choosing to help in our spare time?

Comment: @Duncan something like that. Boss assumes authority, dependency, obligatory job, stuff like that. Volunteers don't have bosses. As for being _that_ polite, I would be happy for guidance to somehow promote / encourage this, but word "boss" just won't let it fly. No sense to put in good advice that will be psychologically rejected by audience due to poor wording

Comment: @gnat I think we need an example in that sentence, since plenty of people have no qualms being rude in real life. Do you have a suggestion for what we can use instead of "boss or colleague"?

Comment: @Laura if I had a suggestion, I would already make it, right here in the answer. :( I need to chew it out, maybe I can wordsmith something. Tough part is, "talk like to a boss" makes such a good match to the way of communication I'd want to encourage, that makes it harder to figure "boss-free" alternative

Comment: @Laura Would it be sufficient to just write: "***You shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, whom you respect.***". It may also be nice to drop the double negatives (shouldn't and wouldn't) when you next edit it.

Comment: @Laura I would probably buy wording like proposed by Duncan ^^^ in comment above. Key word _respect_ could work about as good and is boss-free

Comment: @Duncan: From what I gather, the intent seems to go far beyond that.  The intent appears to be to explicitly disallow statements like "your assumption is wrong; here's why" and "your code is buggy; you have the loops on lines 40 and 41 in the wrong order."  I think this is ridiculous, but perhaps "Don't say anything you wouldn't say to a well-behaved 5-year-old in front of her parents" fits better.

Comment: @tmyklebu Wait, what? The two examples you gave are totally fine...you're allowed to tell people they're wrong, we just want you to be nice about it.

Comment: @Laura: OK.  That's not what I got from the "your boss" passage.  It sounded to me like you wanted people to engage in active coddling while pointing out errors.  (No, this isn't explicitly written anywhere in your policy.  I inferred it from the "be civil" and "choose your words carefully" bullets.)

Comment: @Duncan, cultural differences (also mentioned in other answers or comments about the "boss" phrase) are still an issue with "someone whom you respect". E.g. since you appear to be a fellow Brit, you will probably recognise that some of us tend to be politer to people we despise than to people we esteem (and possibly also politer to people who aren't present than to people who are and can hear our tone of voice).

Comment: @PeterTaylor _Brit style_ politeness is one I find to be especially helpful here. The worse the post, the harder I aim to criticize, the more polite I want my message to appear, to avoid being distracted by whining about "negativity", "rudeness", "personally targeted downvotes". Lazy suckers dropping their thoughtless dumps at us surprisingly tend to put much more effort into complaining about "unfair treatment" and I try to do my best to avoid wasting my time messing with that

Answer (score 14):

> Assume that every question and answer is posted with good intentions.

What does that mean, really? That we should hold that *a priori*, before reading a single word of the post? Or that we must hold that view *despite any kind of evidence to the contrary*? Because if we did that, we would never have reason to flag any post.

Comment: It means that good intentions are the *default assumption*, in the absence of evidence to the contrary. When a post starts with "Hey, Buttwads:", you may consider that to be evidence to the contrary. But, if someone posts a dupe, for example, you should not assume they are "too lazy to even bother search for dupes." The "good intentions" assumption is that "they don't even know they're *supposed* to do that, and the dupe suggester probably didn't show them the right target." (To be clear, it should still be closed as a dupe, but comments (if any) should be educational, not critical.

Comment: @Jaydies That's a good explanation. Perhaps it could be added, because it's not at all what the rule says.

Comment: Hey Buttwads...I really like @Jaydles comment and I agree

Comment: @NickManning, let's try to stay respectful: It's *Doctor* Buttwad" - I didn't spend all those years earning a PhD in Buttwadology only be addressed as plain old "Buttwads."

Answer (score 13):

> Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or religion – and any and all other type of personal attack – is unacceptable

This list is very US-centric, and you're the international site. I would add explicitely to that list the nationality, native language, as well as financial status.

> Please notice that we are an international site and English is not the native language for all of the participants. Don't laugh at someone's mistakes. If the mistake is obvious, just fix it, otherwise ask for clarification.

Comment: Could you help me understand what you mean by the list being US-centric? All of the items contained in that list seem like they would apply to any person, anywhere in the world...I understand your wanting to add nationality / native language to the list; I'm just not clear on what you mean by the rest of the list being US-centric.

Comment: @Laura I mean that it lists explicitely the discrimination issues typical for US, for example concentrating on race. In the Europe, nationality is more the issue, for example. Most Europeans are of the same race, but they are discriminated based on their nationality. And the language issues are probably the most heavy discrimination factor in the international community (while not so obvious in the country where everyone speaks the same language). It's more about accents and the missing items.

Comment: It sounds like a good solution would be to add 'nationality' to the list, and have a section that comments on being generous to people who aren't native English speakers (or the site's primary language, in the case of the non-English sites).

Answer (score 10):

I think the following sentence should change from:

> Refrain from name-calling and other
>   [ad-hominem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem) attacks.

to:

> Refrain from name-calling and other
>   personal attacks.

I'm an articulate speaker, with English as a first language, but I had to follow the link to find out what *ad-hominem* means. I suspect many others will do the same.

I think when you have to provide a link to a Wikipedia article to explain a phrase, it's not suitable for a help article.

Comment: I agree. I also think the word "expletives" is not a commonly used word and could be substituted to make the meaning clearer

Comment: The proposed change would also save us from all those overly pedantic debates about when a personal attack actually is argumentum ad hominem and when it's not.

Comment: I'm also interested in not alienating people. Nothing makes you feel more stupid (or inferior to the author) than having to follow the thoughtfully provided links to understand the big scary word.

Comment: Ad-hominem attack? Stack Overflow podcast [episode 41](http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode41-2009.01.10.mp3) is required listening. See also *[An Open Letter to Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/an-open-letter-to-joel-spolsky-and-jeff-atwood)*.

Answer (score 10):

Laura, sorry, here's another answer for you to read :)

My aim has been:

- reduced text - more chance of people reading it.
- make headings work in isolation (for people who will only skip).
- reduce what I feel is redundant *be civil* - *be respectful*.
- remove specifics of types of harassment. Harassment is harassment, the type is immaterial.
- Include reference to culture/language barrier.
- I also prefer 'avoid' for vulgarity, not an outright ban.

> ### What does 'be nice' *mean* here at Stack Exchange?
>
> **Here we do not accept the unpleasantness that characterises much of the internet.**
>
> **Be respectful**: you are communicating with real people, treat them as you would wish to be treated.
>
> **Be welcoming and patient**: everyone here is either helping others for free, or trying to solve a problem. Assume that every question and
>   answer is posted with good intentions. Be patient with others who may
>   not know everything you know.
>
> **Don't get personal**: direct your criticism at ideas, not at people. Insults, harassment and personal attacks will be sanctioned.
>
> **Choose your words carefully**: people of multiple cultures and languages are present here, what you write may be misunderstood, and
>   you may be misunderstanding what you read. This also applies to humor.
>
> **Avoid vulgarity**: if it's Not Safe For Work, it's Not Safe For Here
>   either.
>
> **Abandon useless disputes**: if you find yourself losing patience, walk away, someone else will take care of it.
>
> **Report bad behavior** if you feel that you are being harassed, or you see someone else being harassed, flag the offending posts. You may also contact
>   Stack Exchange staff directly if you feel that it is necessary.

Comment: A very good write-up. Wish it could be merged with Floris' [practical suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240635).

Comment: That's pretty good, but I don't see the point of "be welcoming and patient" and "abandon useless disputes."  I don't really like calling your document a "code of conduct," though, since that carries with it a connotation of a set of absolute rules.  You've written a concise guide to civilised behaviour, not a ilst of enforceable rules.

Comment: This is very, very good. The "walk away" clause would definitely be nice to have included, and the "bolding for skimmers" is also well-thought.

Comment: @tmyklebu - a list of enforceable rules still relies on community moderators.

Comment: @DeerHunter: Yes.  My point is that making things like "abandon useless disputes" into *rules* means that whether a dispute is "useless" and whether it's been "abandoned" are now subject to review by moderators.  Same goes for whether I chose my words carefully enough.  That doesn't strike me as a positive development.

Comment: @tmyklebu, point taken, what do you think now?

Comment: @Benjol: I think you nailed it.

Answer (score 9):

[Journeyman Geek](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240639/165773) makes good points about keeping things succinct. In my opinion something like:

> #### What is Stack Exchange's code of conduct?
>
> Treat others with respect, assume good intentions, and let us know if you see something wrong. Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to treat you because we’re all here to learn. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know, and bring your sense of humor.
>
> - You shouldn't talk to anyone in a way that you wouldn't do in person.
> - Assume that every question and answer is posted with good intentions. Everyone here is either generously donating their time to help others or is trying to learn something or work through a problem.
> - Focus on the post, not the person. Keep it professional, and avoid criticism of the author. Don't make assumptions about a user's identity, don't do name-calling or other ad-hominem attacks.
> - Choose your words carefully. Profanities are not allowed. Think before posting an inflammatory remark, even as a joke; if you wouldn't say it to a stranger then don't say it here.
> - Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, religion or any other type of personal attack is completely unacceptable. Sexually suggestive language or content is not appropriate for any part of $SiteName, including meta and chat.
>
> If you are uncomfortable with how you or another user is being treated, alert the site moderators by flagging the offending posts. Moderators and Stack Exchange staff will take appropriate action. For the rare case where you think only Stack Exchange staff can handle the situation, contact us directly.

The point is to keep things shorter and digestible without reducing the actual content of each point. Your current version gets so long and rambly it's hard to remember any point but the one you've just read.

Answer (score 8):

> Remember that everyone here is either generously donating their time to help others, or is trying to learn something or work through a problem. Assume that every question and answer is posted with good intentions.

That just isn't true of 90% of the questions here (or at least on Stack Overflow). Not because the askers are bad people, but because they don't understand what the site is about. Until they learn that, as pure as their heart my be, their intentions are not good for the site.

On top of that, often they're *not* actually trying to learn something or work through a problem, they're just trying to get an answer they don't have to work through. Which isn't an evil thing to do, but it's not good for the site.

If you go in expecting that many people will be [help vampires](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/) because they don't know any better, you can try to guide them in the right direction—and many of them will turn into good users (and many of the rest will leave).

If you go in assuming they're already good citizens whose intentions are aligned with the site, you're either going to misinterpret their questions and handle them incorrectly, or get angry at them.

So, as nice as "assume good intentions" sounds, I think it's actually counter-productive. Assume they're good people, and that they want to become good citizens and learn what the right intentions are, but don't assume they already know.

Comment: Aren't their intentions are good enough for us to gently educate them about the purpose of the site? Newbies are not coming here thinking: "Yeah, I know I'm supposed to RTFM and think through the question and post an MWE and only ask questions that are on topic, but screw that. I'm going to try to get an easy answer anyway." They just see that questions get answered, and don't now what to do next, so they ask an inappropriate question. (People first learning in a domain often haven't learned how to develop a good question. Helping them do that does more than helping them participate in SO.)

Comment: @Mars I wasn't suggesting we shouldn't educate anyone. I was merely suggesting that you can't *force* the education, and being nice about it 80 times a day (and getting worse) gets old & tired. You can write all the nice text you want, but there's always going to be a disconnect - the veteran has no idea if the newbie has read it and is ignoring it, or just doesn't know that it exists. The newbie should be smart enough if their question gets down-voted or closed, especially with comments/reasons, to maybe go read the FAQ now without needing kid gloves and hand-holding. Most don't though, IMHO.

Comment: *"That just isn't true of 90% of the questions here (or at least on StackOverflow)"* - Remember that this says "Assume that every question and answer is posted with good intentions", not that "Every question and answer is posted with good intentions."  The difference is huge.  You might be right that not every question is posted with good intentions, but at the same time... the site might be better off if we act as if it were true -- if we phrase our comments and answers as if we assume that questions were posted with good intentions.  You can still vote however you like.

Comment: To be more specific: Can you give concrete examples?  Can you give an example of a comment you would post, in response to a question, based on the assumption that the author might be a help vampire, that wouldn't be just as good if it were phrased based on an assumption of good intentions?  (Also: If you are assuming that the user can be guided in the right direction and can turn into a good user, aren't you implicitly assuming good intentions?)

Comment: @AaronBertrand, OK, fair enough.  One thing I've noticed on SO, in the different languages that I pay attention to, is that there are different newbie patterns with different tools.  Also I don't pay attention to the most popular languages, usually.  You are probably experiencing the problem more than I do.  (For example, Clojure newbies catch on pretty quickly, because they usually have some programming experience.  NetLogo newbies are common, and often very clueless, but innocently so.  But there aren't very many NetLogo questions, so one doesn't get tired of them.)

Comment: @D.W. IMO the problem is the heading of that section, especially the "be welcoming and patient" part. Some behaviour is simply _unwelcome_ on SO, and we should certainly not be _welcoming_ in response to it. If someone post a badly formatted and unresearched question amounting to "google something for me" or "do my work please", we should make it very clear that this type of question (and by extension, any user asking these questions) is _not_ welcome at all. If we sugarcoat this too much, we might as well just abandon any notion of question quality completely.

Comment: @l4mpi Certain types of *questions* being unwelcome is an entirely different issue from being welcoming to *people*. You should still be trying to make an effort to make users feel welcome, even if they don't know all the rules at first. It's possible to tell someone they're question is not a good fit here without making them personally feel like they don't belong; that's what we're getting at here.

Comment: @Laura I object to the idea that I should make users feel welcome who post content that is utterly unwelcome. I would rather make it very clear that they, by extension, are only welcome _to actively contribute_ if their contribution holds any value to the community. Otherwise, they are only welcome to passively lurk until they learn the rules and expected behaviour of the site.

Comment: @l4mpi You don't have to go out of your way to make _anyone_ feel welcome, you just have to refrain from actively making people feel _unwelcome_ through the words that you choose. Being nice doesn't mean not down-voting and closing a crap question. Being respectful simply means not telling the person to take a flying leap in the process. We have things in place to help folks learn how to ask better questions as they continue trying. If you can't say anything nice, then talk with your votes.

Comment: @D.W.: My point is that _assuming_ the question was posted with good intentions, instead of reading it and immediately recognizing that it wasn't, will cause you to bend over backward to make excuses for bad questions, ultimately hurting the asker rather than helping him. (And if it _doesn't_ do that, then it's just a meaningless platitude, so who cares either way?) And on your larger point, that's exactly the point I was trying to make: there's a difference between being a good person (which we can assume) and being a good SO citizen (which we can't).

Comment: @D.W.: As for more specifics: I've posted many comments explaining to people why their question is not a good question, and what they can add to it (which may take some work on their part) to make it a good question. If I were assuming they'd already put in the work, and therefore tried to figure out how to tease a good question out of their incomplete nonsense, they would never get an answer, or at best it would be useless to the site. This way, sometimes they do the work—and then they get a good and answer, and we get a good question and answer that improve the site.

Answer (score 7):

This proposal seems ideal to me. Encouraging people to act well is always a good idea. I do, however, propose an addition.

It is mentioned clearly that discrimination against minorities is unacceptable, and this is laudable. But we need one more step. There are also those who accuse others of such discrimination falsely to allow them to trigger a flow of downvotes. I recently witnessed this happening to another user on Travel.

The biggest problem with such accusations is that many people trust others to have read and understood deeply the content so accused, and are therefore willing to let it be as 'probably true'. Even if they don't agree, they may not flag, subconsciously considering the topic 'tainted'.

So, I propose that the name-calling part could be improved with some extra detail: "This includes accusations of sexism, racism, and homophobia. Whether it is true or not, one of the two deserves a flag."

I do not know any other way to encourage that people take extra time to read posts before judgement. Prejudice against someone because the next post included the word "misogyny" targeted at them falsely is a serious problem.

I just want to be sure to address the fact that being wrong about this subject is as dangerous as ignoring real discrimination.

Comment: I think your point is mostly covered by the "assume good intentions" bit at the beginning of the page...I think it's important enough to call out more explicitly in the bulleted list, though, so keep an eye out for an update.

Comment: @Laura: Thank you. This vector of attack has been growing of late, and it is good to see that a site as widely used as the Stack Exchange is willing to take a stance against it.

Comment: I think a blanket ban on calling people out on violation this section of the rules is misguided.  I think I agree with what you're getting at, that this section of the rules doesn't address all the real-world instances of these issues, but a blanket ban on calling out instances of this essentially discourages meaningful analysis and discussion of instances of sexism, racism, homophobia, etc.

Comment: @Keen: I agree, but such discussion should generally be restricted to the chat. Meaningful analysis is hard to carry out in SE comments, and is not effective against those who hold very strong opinions. These matters inflate to flame wars and name calling very quickly, more so than nearly any other topic. I want to encourage careful thought about things, which results in flagging. I do not want to see people be influenced by others' opinions on this subject, because sexism and racism place a stigma on their target whether called out truly or falsely. Having it too openly displayed is harmful.

Answer (score 7):

This, however, requires people to read, which as we've seen on some sites with on/off topic, people just don't do.

This very incident happened earlier today, when a user (not a new user, either) had a question closed for being off-topic (shopping reccomendation) and got very upset and offended about the question being closed. This could have easily been avoided by simply reading what is on-topic before posting his question. <sup>Link to question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/634113/looking-for-free-web-hosting-for-net-based-web-applications), soon to be deleted.</sup>

[image]

[Full-size image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWiFo.png)

Comment: (Un)fortunately this misses out [comments](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18031533#18031533) from the OP which have been deleted because they were (correctly) flagged as offensive.

Comment: @tombull89 - I am a mod at Money.SE, and we get this same thing now and then. I personally try to welcome the member, and give advice on the nature of the appropriate Q&A before the DVs start or question is closed. For your example, the member clearly has anger issues that are outside the scope of SE. When someone goes off like that, in my opinion, there's little hope to keep them as a member. I am tired of "but my question is about money, how can it possibly be off-topic?" But it's still my job to respond. Kindly.

Comment: You really think Ortund's problem here is due to a "lack of clarity about what acceptable behaviour is and isn't"?  And it's not just that he decided to act childishly?  And that he won't act childishly in the future if he has to read someone's ramblings on civility, sex, and professionalism?

Comment: Sure, of course this isn't perfect.  The proposed code of conduct is not a silver bullet.  It won't solve all problems.  There will still be some problems it doesn't solve.  That doesn't mean it is worthless to try to document expectations, though.  There will be some users who might improve their behavior after a kind note and a link to the code of conduct, and isn't that enough to make it a positive thing?

Comment: Could you please start removing avatars and names when posting such screenshots? PS or MS Paint might help you to _not_ call single people out. Public shaming is not a good thing.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly a situation I think we need to deal with. Not the original poster, but the responses to said poster. Maybe one comment in that screenshot is civil, and even that one is debatable. When someone gets like this, we still need to follow the rules, and avoid provoking them any further. Something like "Just because you see someone else being even extremely uncivil doesn't mean you should respond in kind," would be a great addition to the conduct code. Across the entire Internet, it is the most common mistake, even made by people who are otherwise impeccably nice.

Comment: This post itself seems to fall outside of the rules as just posted. If you're trying to talk about a systematic problem, there's no need to call out the specific user, and you can censor their name. Leaving their name in, IMHO, counts as a (mild) form of harassment.

Comment: I believe if there is a way to transfer this question to the relevant forum organically, this actually wouldn't be a problem. His question was innocent enough, I believe. And unlike many people here, most people don't have a lot of time IRL. It's going to be irritating.

Comment: @trlkly what is debatable about my comment?

Comment: @trlkly: I think the responses to the asker here were appropriate once he decided to lower the level of discourse.  I do not think you're going to stop humans from reacting like humans by instituting a bunch of rules.

Comment: @raptortech97 the name is a pseudonym, it's in an image and so not going to show up on Google when people Google for the pseudonym, the user doesn't know they've been posted about, and nobody who reads this is going to care enough to go out of their way to interact with that user on SE just to be a dick to them. Where is the harassment here? I literally have no idea what potential harm you could be seeing in 'calling a user out' besides the ones above, nor what definition of "harassment" you're using such that this qualifies.

Answer (score 7):

This is horrible. It's longer than the old one, and it says less.

> This community has earned a reputation for avoiding ugliness, harassment, and bigotry because people like you have refused to allow
>   it.

Among whom has "the community" earned this reputation? What qualifies as "ugliness"? Harassment and bigotry are genuinely bad, but you've written this like you have no idea what they are. Furthermore, I don't see why you'd fill space in a "code of conduct" with something like this.

> Please treat others with respect, assume good intentions, and let
>   us know if you see something wrong. This isn't always easy, so we
>   created a non-exhaustive set of principles intended to help all of us
>   communicate well. Here are some specific guidelines to keep in mind:
>
> The real-life test: You shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, including a boss or new
>   colleague. Always conduct yourself in a respectful manner.

These two sentences are contradictory. I treat people disrespectfully in real life quite often if they're disrespectful themselves or if they're about to do something dangerous and they don't seem to realise it. Are you sure you meant to write the first sentence?

> We're all in this together, so be welcoming and patient. Remember that everyone here is either generously donating their time
>   to help others, or is trying to learn something or work through a
>   problem. Assume that every question and answer is posted with good
>   intentions. Treat others with the same respect you’d want them to
>   treat you because we’re all here to learn, together. Be patient with
>   others who may not know everything you know, and bring your sense of
>   humor.

This is false and everyone knows it. Lots of people come to Stack Overflow, because they're in the middle of an interview and they can't solve the problem, or because they have a homework assignment that they want someone else to do. Writing this sort of thing in an official document discredits both the document and its author.

Also, why did you need to bring up the "respect" thing again? You've already said it.

> Focus on the post, not the person. Keep it professional, and avoid criticism of the author, (as opposed to the post). Don't make
>   assumptions about a user's identity, and avoid references to
>   demographics unless they are an essential part of the question or
>   answer. Refrain from name-calling and other ad-hominem attacks.

You already covered "keep it professional" two paragraphs ago.

> Choose your words carefully. Expletives are generally not allowed; don't be vulgar. Think before posting an inflammatory remark,
>   even as a joke: if it isn't appropriate at work or home, it is not
>   appropriate here.

Why weaken "expletives are not allowed" by inserting a weasel word?

Not everybody is from your home, not everybody works with you, and certain things that aren't appropriate in polite conversation may well be appropriate at work or at home depending on the particular situation. Why are you making assumptions about our lives one paragraph after you implored us not to make assumptions about others?

> Be civil. Attacking or harassing individuals based on gender, sexual orientation, disability, gender identity, age, race, or
>   religion – and any and all other type of personal attack – is
>   unacceptable.
>   Sexually suggestive language, imagery, and attention are
>   not appropriate for any part of $SiteName, including meta and chat.

You covered harassing people already. I understand that the explicit enumeration is required for some legal reason.

> If
>   you are being harassed, notice that someone else is being harassed, or
>   have any other concerns, please alert the site moderators immediately
>   by flagging the offending post(s). Moderators and/or Stack Exchange
>   staff will investigate the issue and take appropriate action. For the
>   rare case where you think only Stack Exchange staff can handle the
>   situation, contact us directly.

This adds something to the previous "Be nice" section. Why not just add this to the old page?

Answer (score 7):

I want to suggest adding the following:

> **Do not provoke:** If your post (especially comments) can be interpreted by reasonable people as having an intent of provoking
>   negative response from other member(s) of the community then it is not
>   welcome here. If you can not post it a way that is not likely to be
>   taken as provocative then do not post it.

I think most of the behavior we are wanting to curtail happens in comments and are the result of comments that would fit in here. These comments are in general not constructive or productive anyway and even though often they have a legitimate concern they often seem intentionally phrased in a way that is intended to provoke rather than to help or clarify.

Comment: I don't think any criticism has ever been written that can't be "interpreted by reasonable people as having an intent of provoking negative response."  People can be really, really sensitive.

Comment: Its one thing to upset someone its another to post with the intent of upsetting someone.  Most people can see the difference when they are not the target of the comment.  It gets harder to differentiate when you are the target though I will agree.  And for the record I am open to edits to make this clearer or more easily assessed

Comment: It's one thing to post with the intent of upsetting someone and it's quite another to post in a way that someone else will interpret as upsetting.  It's impossible to ban the former, so you're proposing to ban the latter.  It's massively overbroad.

Comment: This is a good thought, but I'd say -- at least in its current wording -- that it fails the "people who need to be told this aren't going to recognize it" test. I will think on different ways of writing it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - My thought is it gives the mods some latitude in making judgement and the community some teeth in complaining about the less helpful posts.

Comment: @tmyklebu I think it is generally possible to determine whether someone posted with the intent to offend. The only real exception is when they deliberately try to hide their intentions. Sure, the latter may get off light, but we should still stop the former. I also don't buy that posting in a manner that most people would not find offensive is all that difficult. And, when you do accidentally offend, apologies go a long way in helping with the problem and indicating you didn't mean to provoke.

Comment: @trlkly: Sure.  But, in anything close to a borderline case, different people are going to come up with different answers.  What do you do then?

Comment: @tmyklebu To answer your question directly: have both sides make their arguments, and then have a moderator make the final decision. But my point is that I don't think this situation happens as often as you'd think. Usually there's just one person who mistakenly thinks the person intended to offend--the person who got offended. Outsiders looking in can usually tell that isn't the case. On the other hand, if someone means to offend, I think pretty much everyone agrees, save for maybe the guy who is always somewhat acerbic.

Comment: @trlkly: I (now, after Laura clarified) believe this rule is intended to give moderators more to stand on when they do clean up offensive material.  Currently they are quite conservative doing so, and I hope that continues.  However, the rule enforced by moderators is something like "if the moderator who sees your material thinks it's clearly off-base, he will delete it."  This works and does not require moderators to judge the poster's intent.  What do you feel this proposal would add or subtract from the status quo?

Comment: @tmyklebu - I think that people who do not have a history of this type of behavior get the benefit of the doubt, and those that are regularly being warned about it do not.  If the regular provacateurs want to continue to participate then they will need to go out of their way to make sure they are not being provacative.  That is really the goal anyway.

Comment: @Chad: Do the "regular provocateurs" on Workplace and the like somehow fail to violate the "be nice" rule or the thing Laura currently has up?  If not, why is another rule necessary?

Comment: Its not just the workplace.  And yes there are alot of creative programmer types here that are really good at going right up to that line or appearing to be on the right side of that line but know that what they are doing is likely to cause problems.

Comment: @Chad: How do you propose to fix this problem that you perceive?  Your current suggestion does not appear to do anything to anything other than encourage moderators to censor more liberally.

Comment: @tmyklebu Through community moderation and flags.  That is how it is supposed to work.  The rule just makes it explicit that this type of behavior is to be avoided period.

Comment: @Chad: So basically you're proposing...no change at all?  By adding a paragraph about provocation?

Comment: @tmyklahu - I am proposing that this phrase makes it clear that provacative comments are not welcome.  And gives teeth for moderation activities

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange currently permits "sexually suggestive language and imagery" where its use is essential and strictly on topic. We have a biology site where I don't think you want to ban discussion of the **biological aspect of sexual relations**. We also have religion sites where matters of **sexual morality** often reach the hot list.

Users should be encouraged to be cautious, to report sexual harrassment, and yet to welcome honest on-topic enquiry.

Comment: The rule seems more to prevent things like sexist or crude remarks.  Frank, on-topic discussions of sexual topics aren't related to this rule.

Comment: @Keen, I am sure that is the intent, and I fully support that intent. Further, I think it might discourage provocative question titles, that I also think are harmful to the communities here. But I want to highlight the possibility of collateral damage to frank, explicit Q&A about sex.

Comment: @Qsigma, I encourage you to give more concrete examples of how you think this langugae could cause collateral damage.  Right now your comment is a bit abstract.

Answer (score 4):

The spirit of the updated laws is awesome. But--first, despite the length my comment will accrue (& it will)--I <3 Brevity. Please; forbear a moment with an old EULA hostage-negotiator & reference publisher? Responses to the actual wording, imvho, point to a general issue: the code tries to cover the widest possible range of infractions, & thus creates the *wrong kind of stack*. The user-objections imply that some of this rewording is less suited to an FAQ-friendly code of action than it might be to a "See also:" reference at the end, or a EULA (sorry). Example: instead of simply declaring that "Ad hominem attacks are unacceptable in any circumstance. Period" we are given instead a lengthy *definition* of "ad hominem." Such a definition vastly increases the likelihood of people begging questions like that of "expletives", while in fact, defining either is unnecessary in a basic code.

It should be possible to work in a (very) pithy preface defining "civil" language & demeanor on this site--because, this code *is* exemplary--but removing the contractual legalese should enhance clarity & increase adherence to le Code Stackexchange. Besides, a code of conduct like this deserves better than to stray into "defined, for the purposes of this Agreement" territory, as though it was attempting to sneak T&Cs past the unwary.

For the benefit of users who need clarification of a term like "expletives" (tho' that might cover more ground if "condescending or judgmental modifiers & expletives" were classed with ad hominem attacks as point-blank unacceptable): definition of  a few choice terms could appear *after* the body of the text, with a link to a preferred dictionary for readers seeking further enlightenment. PS: Ty for removing the vague & always-suspect "nice" :).

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't "Attacking or harassing individuals is unacceptable." be much simpler and more complete than the current list of specific offenses?

As written it sounds like only some kinds of harassment (those explicitly mentioned) are unwelcome. For example, harassing and attacking someone on non-personal grounds seems to be all right (like when their posts use a programming language I don't like).

If indeed all forms of harassment are unwelcome it would be much simpler to just write that. That would then obviously also contain harassment based on gender, harassment based on age, ...

Answer (score 3):

I really hate it; I think the former version was much better.

I am talking about a bunch of sites (so, *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)*, some others coming out of [Area 51](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange#History) now), not Stack Exchange in general: those places are not work, aren't home, it is not out with friends. Maybe the company behind Stack Exchange would have a big advantage in making this like a workplace, I don't know. Anyway, I do not like bullying, but direct, honest, flamboyant, frank and maybe rude talking is often part of what places are full of nerds, not geeks, like I am.

I would reword the whole paragraph to

> Do not say anything Linus wouldn't write in LKML.

Comment: Not "Do not say anything Ulrich Drepper wouldn't write?"  Or Theo de Raadt or something? :)

Comment: @tmyklebu "Do not say anything you ever thought the average 40yrs old linux guy would say in front of L.Poettering". Deal?

Comment: Yeah, because LKML is such a shining example of tolerance: https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/10/6/432 https://lkml.org/lkml/2014/10/4/79

Comment: @BradLarson I think you missed my point in the previous paragraph. That kind of message you linked, may fit a ml but obviously not a q&a site. It is gratuitous, off-topic, nerdy and very sad; but anyway I would hate somebody _censoring_ that in a mailing list. Nothing to do with plenty of other technical messages there, with a similar tone, and the fact that that tone could be acceptable in here.

Comment: @guido - Those kind of messages have no place in a mailing list I'd ever want to participate in. Linus himself is not a model anyone here should follow: http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/07/linus-torvalds-defends-his-right-to-shame-linux-kernel-developers/ . Frankly, if he behaved on SE the way he does on that mailing list, we'd probably end up having to suspend him.

Comment: @BradLarson the world is beautiful because it is varied; if SE will take another route it is perfectly fine with me, i'll participate whenever i want - and following the rules - yet my ideal model was a technical slashdot. Conversely, censorship is a real problem in today internet, and the `is not a model anyone here should follow` really really makes me sad.

Comment: @BradLarson: Yes, crazies sometimes post to LKML.  Seems like they're usually ignored or TTFO, and LKML winds up being a wonderfully productive place of discussion.  Doesn't seem like any sort of pasteurisation effort is needed there.

Answer (score 2):

> The real-life test: You shouldn't talk to anyone here in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, including a boss or new colleague. Always conduct yourself in a respectful manner.

This is ambiguous. Everyone behaves the way they would talk to *somebody* in person; If they're rude here, there's always *someone* they'd be rude to in person. Replace with: "...*in a way that you wouldn't talk to someone in person, **in a professional setting,** including a boss...*"

> We're all in this together, so be welcoming and patient.

The "we're all in this together" is patronizing and inflammatory. It adds nothing; remove it.

> Choose your words carefully. Expletives are generally not allowed; don't be vulgar. Think before posting an inflammatory remark, even as a joke: if it isn't appropriate at work or home, it is not appropriate here.

I think this is more clear:
***Choose your works carefully.*** Avoid all offensive language, including offensive words, phrases, and jokes. Remember that what you post here effectively becomes your résumé; moderate your language accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

There is precious little that the new (old?) code adds to the table. It reads like something promulgated by the Office of Harassment Prevention and Groupthink.

- There's too much talk about sex in the policy. Sex harassment, gender discrimination, sexual images. Can be replaced with "**S**tack **Ex**change doesn't care about sex, and you shouldn't, either".
- Is issuing the code of conduct **really necessary**? A well-behaving community already does moderate all the stuff you mentioned and plenty of what has gone unsaid. The **be nice** rule was elegant in its simplicity and reliance on community consensus.

Printing out new policies every other week is a sure sign of bureaucracy. Are you sure you want to turn Stack Exchange into another Wikipedia?

EDIT: based on Robert Harvey's remarks, I can understand that this policy is written by lawyers and is intended to exculpate Stack Exchange as a business entity from allegations of sitting for so long without a formal anti-harassment code of conduct. If it is mandated legally, **I see no point in discussing it**. Simply lock the post, and be done with it. Also be done with the spirit of community moderation, as well.

Comment: "promulgated by the Office of Harassment Prevention"... you and I had the same gut reaction there... but I disagree with the "essentially about sex" bit of your post.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - at least part of the "Focus on the post" item mentions the other user's **identity**. "Be nice" captures all the nicety and leaves out the legal detritus, instead.

Comment: Yes.  Given the stark difference between the very specific legal verbiage and the very general "be nice" guidance, I'd say that a significant portion of this policy is legally motivated.  It's unlikely that the lawyers will see your point of view.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - then why should the community ever bother with discussing this code? If it is pushed on Stack Exchange sites from the powers-that-be and cannot be changed without proving you're a member of the ABA, there's no need in asking the question.

Comment: -1 for yet another knee jerk reaction to the company seeking input on an integral part of the network.

Comment: @Vogel612 - why seek input if the policy is already set?

Comment: They wouldn't seek input if it were... This isn't a blog announcement. It's a meta-discussion for a reason. And your answer is frankly speaking not constructive to that discussion...

Comment: @Vogel612 - there's big difference between genuine discussion and an attempt to legitimize pre-cooked policy.

Comment: I will just ... no nevermind. I think you are seeing this from a negative viewpoint. I will most probably not be able to actually discuss with you. So... YMMV ;)

Comment: Just to clarify: this isn't written or motivated by our lawyers. It's motivated by Stack Exchange caring about creating a place filled with respectful and respected individuals. We've noticed some issues with behavioral expectations not being clear, so we're trying to clarify expectations. We want to signal to new users that harassment, disrespect, and other undesirable behavior isn't tolerated here, and to make sure *all* users can agree on the basic categories of behavior that are not allowed.

Comment: If you don't care to discuss the content of our code of conduct, that's perfectly fine. I've actually gotten some useful feedback here about changes we can make to the wording to make things clearer, though, so I'm pretty happy with this thread. It can all still be summed up by the phrase "be nice"; we've just provided some expanded guidance for times when it might not be so obvious to a user.

Comment: @Laura - would like to thank you for your effort. Think that [Floris' answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240594/proposed-new-code-of-conduct-for-all-stack-exchange-sites/240635) condenses the best ideas that can be put into the code of conduct.

Comment: @Laura - although putting the changes live could have been postponed till some reasonable time has elapsed since the beginning of the discussion in Meta. There, perhaps, lies a watershed between listening to opinions and autocratic decision-making.

Comment: +1 for the original answer and +1 after the edit. if this comes from the layers of SE, we cannot do anything else that embrace it, but as there is no point in discussing it, do not make it like it was a community product

Comment: @DeerHunter, fair point: it would have been clearer that we genuinely want input (and will use it) if we'd waited to post this version. But don't trust me telling you: just watch it. We're definitely incorporating a number of the suggestions here. As to calling it "autocratic", which seems to assume we won't really take feedback... maybe we do need to be a *little* specific about things like  we ask folks to "assume good faith".  :P (Which, as others have pointed out, could be better highlighted.)

Comment: Just to be crystal clear: Not one single lawyer was involved in this.  And it had nothing to do with liability or other legal concerns. It's okay to think it's too long, or specific, but please don't think it's some kind of legal CYA BS.  It's just about being as clear as we can about what you can expect here.

Comment: @Laura You are being unrealistic in expecting that new users will read the code of conduct.  Adding even more stuff for them to read just makes it even less likely that they will read it.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if people read it on their own @WarrenDew (although it would be nice). I'd go as far as saying that most people on SE don't even need to bother with it at all. For the few that may step out of line every now and then, it would be nice if we had clear documentation to point them at and help them understand the error in their ways.

Answer (score 1):

"This community has earned a reputation for avoiding ugliness, harassment, and bigotry" - so it sounds like we're in pretty good shape, no?  So why do we want to change things, again?  If it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: I'd love to see evidence in support of this claim.

Comment: I don't know. I personally have a real problem with there being a censor for politeness. It just goes against all evidence of humanity we've witnessed so far. What this site needs to make as its core aim is honesty and the truth. Keeping bars on human behavior (proven wrong in human history) is not the way. Expletives can be bad, but they can also be necessary. Wilful emotional blindness keeps this site open for abuse and out of touch with reality.

Answer (score -2):

I'll post a few rules on the quality and respect I believe to be important :)

## Quality

- Search before posting either answers or questions - *try* not to duplicate (well-known :) )
- If you posted an answer, evaluate all another answers as if you didn't post an answer, vote on them to reflect **quality**, don't downvote other posts to raise your post up
- Don't post answers or questions just to gain reputation, because it will be negatively reflected on your posts (again, **quality**)
- Don't complete review tasks to get badges, it will reduce site's **quality** and will (of course) lead to review suspension
- If you see that a post has some typos, don't be lazy - correct them

## Respect

- Don't abuse your privileges - otherwise you don't merit the reputation you have
- Do not touch "dark past" of any of users - its between this user and moderators
- Don't measure reputation of the OP as the quality of the post, don't vote on the post considering only reputation of its owner - any trusted user can post a bad answer and any new user can post a genius answer
- **Respect** new users: they base their first opinion on the replies they received to their first posts

Comment: This is about a general code of conduct for personal behavior on these sites, not elements specific to Stack Exchange. The above points might belong somewhere else, but not in a typical code of conduct.

Comment: How should respect not be part of a code of conduct? I agree with you the quality part doesn't fit, but that's only half the post.

Comment: I think most people assume the first half of the post takes greater priority than the second half. Why else would Quality come before Respect? Having said that, I think downvoting for the sake of raising your own is not nice. Maybe remove/disallow votes if you provide an answer. This removes the opportunity for self-interested individuals from downvoting someone else's answer.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion, if you are hoping to create an inviting and helpful learning environment, define "harmful behavior" as impatient, demeaning, unhelpful, unkind, or sarcastic and then suspend or expel members who engage in harmful behavior.

Are consequences necessary? Yes, they are! Consequences are necessary for the same reasons that necessitated a code of conduct.

Joe

Comment: I assume this goes for users that post questions and those that try to figure out what the answer could be? A recent example: *do you saw Code of Conduct message? Go away, if cannot really help. Thanks.*  Is that worth a suspension and if yes, for which user?

Comment: Note: this question is obsolete, and there's no real point posting feedback on this superseded text. It's already been rewritten.

Answer (score -6):

I simply want to *agreeably* say, **Amen!**

**Edit:** I have read and re-read the "*Proposed new code of conduct for all Stack Exchange sites*" and I have decided to be positive and support the "Proposed" Constitution just the way it is, I don't, in my sober mind find anything *missing* or wrong. That's why I said: AMEN! as in, **It makes sense to me the way it is proposed, no less, no more and I fully second the motion**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: **AMEN** means "So be it"... I have read and re-read the "_Proposed new code of conduct for all Stack Exchange sites_" and I have decided to be positive and support the "Proposed" Constitution. That's why I said: *AMEN!* as in **It makes sense to me the way it is proposed, no less, no mere and I fully second the motion**

Comment: Why the downvote?... The Question was: **Is there anything we missed that is essential for creating the expectation that Stack Exchange communities are civil and respectful?** and my answer simply states. *NO, I read everything and I think it is perfect the way it is*... So, why **downvote**?... Is it a crime to appreciate a well written code of conduct?

Comment: I am not permitted to upvote, as yet, so am attempting to work within the constraints. Regardless, my remark re "nice" was perhaps superfluous (ty ;).

Comment: This is a comment. Answers here should provide some insight or propose some change, this answer doesn't do any of these. It's plain noise.

Comment: OK, one more try: edit the updated content for clarity. As it stands it does not read like a viable Code of Conduct. Cut excess definitions or implement them as suggested here, which are in line with comments by other users. The intent is admirable, but to be a viable code of action it requires some ruthless editing. And the last comment is Unacceptable under the proposed update even sans edits ;).

Comment: This answer is fine; I basically asked a yes or no question at the end of the original question above, and this answer says "no, you didn't miss anything."

Comment: @Laura so you're OK with 100 "Yes" or "No" answers? Isn't it just noise better suited as comments?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'm okay with *one* "I don't have anything to add" answer :)

Comment: So am just being victimized for giving my honest opinion??... **2DownVotes??**... Don't I have the right to approve of a **well thought out** _Proposed new code of conduct for all Stack Exchange sites_ Why make my **HARD-EARNED privileges** suffer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why should I "**_propose Change_**" if everything is ok to me.... Why Change what is very intelligently written by someone/people wise enough to draft such a _conduct_?... I like it the way it is, what's wrong with me liking something that is good according to me???

Answer (score -6):

Read the complete code of conduct. I am in 90% favour of it. It is very important to follow the site behaviour to make it user-friendly and positive.
Harassing someone or down-voting individual only because you don't like his/her posts is unacceptable. Writing jargons is a bad idea to express yourself here.

But after reading the code of conduct from start to end I feel that a *computer generated* post can follow this code of conduct in perfection. Your answer must be an answer in the way as we develop a software and it output the exact result according to the input given. Else your post is a *bug*.

Comment: Harassing and downvoting are very different things. Downvoting is certainly the expected response when a post is of bad quality in your eyes, ideally followed by comments. Harassing is completely unrelated. As an example, I downvoted your post because it is, in my eyes, of low quality.

Answer (score -6):

I think it could stand to be much more proactive on addressing gender, in particular. I know women who simply refuse to post here. The proposed wording (outlawing "attacks" and "harrassment") wouldn't give them much confidence that they'll be looked after. It doesn't rule out sexist jokes or sexist examples, for instance.

Stronger wording would say something like:

> Women are *very welcome* here. Any behaviour that makes women feel unwelcome or uncomfortable will not be tolerated. This includes sexist jokes, sexist examples, sexist language, or reference to gender when it is not relevant.

Comment: If something you say to someone else could be interpreted by a reasonable person as being (1) threatening, demeaning or insulting and (2) deliberately so, then I'm certain that we've defined 'not allowed' without having to be any more specific than we're already being, in _any_ case that it could possibly manifest. Sexist remarks or jokes fall squarely into demeaning in my book. I am *glad* that people are thinking well beyond themselves here, it makes me feel good that you folks want everyone covered. I think we've got that with what we have.

Comment: @TimPost Ok, here's a different part of the same issue: the language in the code of conduct is about what the victim of personal attacks etc needs to do about it. Could there be clearer statements about what will happen to the person doing it? (Compare http://confcodeofconduct.com/) I just get this uneasy feeling of "We all have good intentions here, right guys?" and not much serious weight behind it.

Comment: @SteveBennett, that choice (focusing on the *good* actors) is deliberate. Goals in order are: A) To let the good guys know they shouldn't see BS here like on much of the internet, (and what to do if they do), B) to remind those of us with flaws who mean well what to be especially careful of, and C) to give us, mods, and others a *little* (broadly worded) air cover to point to when we do nuke really bad stuff. The reader should want to believe they can be one of the good guys - if they're committed to the dark side, threats here won't change that, and we're happy suspending them anyway.

Comment: I removed most of the comments here; they were tangential, argumentative, and not working towards any resolution, and many were rather rude. You can disagree with the answer, but do so constructively, and use [chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) if you want to have an extended conversation.

Answer (score -25):

Speaking for myself, I find the quick and silent downvote of a question by the people who run these sites to be the total antithesis of "nice". It's one thing to downvote newbie questions that are clearly someone asking for answers to their homework, but it's used far too often on other occasions.  It never fails to make me angry, since it ignores the thought I did put into the question, to the point where I will shy away from using Stack Overflow which was once a very useful resource. All this code of conduct stuff is making the site worse.

As for "not enough research shown", I never post anything on Stack Overflow unless I've done quite a bit of research beforehand even if I don't necessarily post citations to prove it.

Comment: Downvoted for caring way too much about random downvotes.

Comment: Voting is intended to convey a judgement about quality and the fidelity of that signal is more important than 'being nice' if that would otherwise require dishonesty or dissembling.

Comment: Really?  The silent downvote frankly reminds me of high school.  You're not one of the cool kids, we won't even talk to you.  You want civility, you should have the civility to explain why you're doing the downvote.  If you don't have time to do that, don't downvote.  How would you make the question more useful?

Comment: This answer has absolutely nothing to do with the proposed code of conduct.

Comment: It has much to do with the proposed code of conduct.  You want people to behave nicely but don't want to address the reasons why people don't always do so.

Comment: People are already encouraged to explain their downvotes. There's nothing more that can or should be done about that.

Comment: People are encouraged to explain their downvotes.  Yet they often don't and that's not a problem?  I don't understand the reasoning here.

Comment: You can't force people to be courteous. If someone isn't interested in explaining their downvote, they won't, and there's nothing (productive) we can do about it.

Comment: If you can't force people to be courteous, what's the point of a code of conduct that says "be nice"?

Comment: The code of conduct refers to your interactions with other people. Voting is an interaction with a post, not a person.

Comment: What @Yannis said; I can remain civil (as I am here), and yet down vote your post (which I have here). While people are encouraged to explain their votes, it's not required. Adding such a statement to the Code of Conduct would certainly seem to be doing more than 'encouraging'. But ultimately, it's also outside of the scope of a Code of Conduct.

Comment: Well, @Yannis, that's at least an explanation.  I still don't agree with it, but it explains where you're coming from.    If you want people to remain civil and not fly off the handle, perhaps it would be good not to disrespect their posts by an anonymous downvote.  I consider myself to have been a useful member of this site.  I have gotten good information here.  Less frequently, I've helped others.  But still, an anonymous downvote is inevitably experienced as a putdown, and too many more of these and I'll find another way.  I don't think this does the site any favors.

Comment: I don't disagree that an anonymous downvote can be frustrating, especially when you've put some effort in your post. Regardless, every proposed solution I've seen (forcing downvote comments, etc) would be disastrous. The only solution that works I know of is to accept anonymous downvotes as a necessary evil, and stop caring about magic internet points all together.

Comment: @Yannis I don't mind downvotes requiring a reason. I don't think it should be part of comments. It should be hidden and only revealed if you click on the number between the upvote/downvote arrows. For those interested in the reason, they can see, but it shouldn't be a comment.

Comment: Requiring me to provide an explanation every time I downvote an obvious piece of crap would get old very soon @sunk818.

Comment: @Yannis Exactly. Downvoting shouldn't receive the same efficiency as upvoting. Perhaps you'd be more judicious in your downvoting.

Comment: If I have to leave an explanation for how to improve a post when I downvote, then the poster should be leaving an explanation for how they can improve on their post whenever someone upvotes, right?  Sounds about fair.

Comment: @sunk818 the purpose of SE isn't to cater to the lazy, the offensive, the illiterate, or the rude.

Comment: @fbueckert Upvotes don't require an explanation as it is self explanatory, however; downvotes do not have the same luxury as people ask for an explanation. I rarely see anyone asking for explanation on why something was upvoted.

Comment: @enderland, why do you assume that reason for downvoting would further encourage those kind of qualities. There is enough scale here for answers to race to the bottom even if it required a reason.

Comment: @sunk818 *That's the point*.  You're making the assumption that votes are personal.  They are not.  They are judgements of post quality, and any barrier thrown in the way of voting (up *or* down), means less of it will happen.  Can't really get an accurate assessment of a post if you're telling those who downvote that they have to justify it.

Comment: In fact @Yannis is giving *the* explanation, which is at the core of your frustration and the quite inappropriateness of this answer and your reaction to downvotes in general. And this is not only where *he* is coming from, but where the whole SE framework's policy is coming from. **You don't vote on people, you vote on posts**. That's all there is to it and once you've realized this, a downvote will hurt much less.

Comment: @fbueckert I have seen eBay and amazon require more details for negative feedback. You just need a sort order for answer ranking. Not everyone needs to down vote if the answer is already where it belongs. I say push it out on a community as a test feature and evaluate after some data is gathered.

Comment: @sunk818: I suspect downvoters will simply leave empty, near-empty, or useless explanations. There's no real way you can enforce a reasoning for every downvote when a user always has the option to just hold down the "a" key for 5 seconds.

Comment: @Ellesedil Try it and see. We all have our opinions. Only actual testing will reveal the behavior of the community. I think everyone's statement is true to some extent. Some opinions will be edge cases not deserving of strong consideration, while other opinions will closely reflect reality. Try it and see.

Comment: @sunk818 Or you can come up with an argument that hasn't been tried before.  Tests *have* been done, and when erecting barriers, less people will pass that barrier.  That means you wouldn't get a true measure of the post's quality.  Whatever barrier you erect, you have to ensure it's there for both downvotes *and* upvotes.  Doing it for only one means it's unbalanced.

Comment: I was just about to say something along those lines, @fbueckert - keeping the accessibility of upvoting and downvoting the same helps ensure balance and provide an actually clear view of how the community feels about something.

Comment: Furthermore, in the vast majority of cases, the reason for a downvote is very obvious. Either the user hasn't put in even a modicum of effort to find the answer for themselves, they haven't bothered with correct use of English (spelling, proper sentences, etc.), or the community is divided on something (such as whether a specific type of question is appropriate for a site - in this case you will often see these questions downvoted out of principle)

Comment: **This** is a great example of why we felt we needed to expand "be nice" into a full-on code of conduct: "nice" is subjective. Being civil and constructive toward your peers is admirable; self-censoring in fear that someone's feelings will be hurt isn't. [Being nice does not mean being dishonest.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/)

Comment: Well, ironically, the downvotes that got me here now have an explanation attached, which they did not at the time I started this.  And it helps.  And it was a canned explanation.  And that's okay.  It still is more informative than nothing.

Comment: downvoting/upvoting is a signal, a measurement.  It's like looking at a meter that swings one way or the other.  If SO/SE wants me to contribute to that process of signal generation, then requiring an explanation for downvoting cannot be mandatory. If it is or becomes mandatory, my process of contributing to signal generation will be drastically curtailed.  I don't care if that is rude or not.  It is a factual statement of what my behavior would be.  I have niether the time nor the motivation to be engaged in an argument about every vote I cast.  I would prefer not to vote, in that case.

Comment: Suppose there were about five or six "radio buttons" for downvotes.  One being "other".  "Downvoted for not enough research".  "Downvoted for looking for opinons".  This would help, IMHO.

Comment: Then those same options have to be there for upvotes.  Anything that creates more work for voting needs to applied equally to both up and downvotes.  Unless you want to add that same option to upvotes, that barrier will inherently skew the votes upwards.  And that means the judgement of quality isn't going to be fair.

Comment: Think about it; I find a post I like.  I go to upvote it.  The system says, "Hey, why do you like this post?"  I decide it's not worth upvoting anymore.  It's no longer a proper judgement of quality, as I decided the trouble to upvote isn't worth it.  It's the exact same with downvotes.

Comment: @fbueckert +1. Explaining downvotes is even more burdensome, because now you have to deal with somebody wanting to debate you over it.

Comment: @WillieWheeler That's due to people perceiving upvotes as confirmation of their skills and abilities, while downvotes are the opposite.  Everybody wants confirmation, but either want criticism in a tangible form to debate, or challenge to confirm/deny their shortfalls.  Which I think is something we really need to work on; taking it personally is pretty ingrained, when it's not a judgement of the person.  More user education on that front would be very beneficial, I feel.

Comment: @SteveCohen Well said. I see people often saying go and learn first before you post something here. Stackexchange has never been welcoming. People make you feel that you have invaded their personal space and are wasting their time.

Comment: @New Stack Exchange is very welcoming, *as long as you make a minimum effort*. Asking a question that can be answered by Google is a waste of everyone's time. If you're not feeling welcome because your questions are being downvoted, you may want to consider the possibility that other people are not the problem.

Comment: @IanKemp Kindly read my comment again. I did not say that downvoting is making me not feel welcome. I don't know what made you come to that conclusion. People assume too much. And how do you define that the question can/cannot be answered by google. If answers are in google no one is going to come here asking for help. You know how difficult and time consuming it is to ask a question here.

Comment: @sunk818: _"Not everyone needs to down vote if the answer is already where it belongs_" That's absurd. Who decides "where it belongs"? That's right: it's decided by a sum total of the votes that everybody wanted to cast on it. If an answer is at -5 and I am the last human being left on Earth to vote on it, and I feel it deserves a downvote, then it "belongs" at -6. Suggesting that I withhold my vote because it already "belongs" at -5 is not only illogical, but circular. It's also undemocratic to suggest that I should not get my say just because some other people already had a similar say.

Comment: I upvoted you because I have empathy. <3

Comment: @Yannis - You misunderstand me when you advise me to "stop caring about magic Internet points." In fact, I don't give a crap about them. I do care that the effort I've made to put a post together, not to mention the effort I've undergone BEFORE posting, have gone to waste. Experience tells me that a downvoted post is much less likely to get a substantive response than one that has no response. An explanation might lead one to improve it. A bare downvote incentivizes one to incivility. A bare downvote is intended as a way of ending discussion. This is clear from some of the comments above.

Comment: You've gotten *pages* of comments telling you why downvotes don't, and will never, require comments.  You are free to disagree if you don't agree with them, but suggesting that bare downvotes are censors, is *dramatically* off the mark.  You're still seeing them as personal attacks.  I'd suggest you spend some time trying to keep the quality up on a site.  You'll very quickly see what downvotes are good for.

Comment: This whole thread is about a "code of conduct".  "Don't take it personal".  "Be nice".  And yet, those with the power to downvote, when questioned on it, if the questioner doesn't go away, eventually devolve into "Requiring me to provide an explanation every time I downvote an obvious piece of crap".  Accused of asking a question that could easily be answered on Google.  Hey, I spent hours on Google before posting my "obvious piece of crap".  It happens.  You want a well run site, you do need a bit more empathy.  I might view it differently in your shoes, but this is a valuable dialog.

Comment: I'm not saying that downvoters are deliberately censoring, but regardless of your intent, a downvote DOES have that effect.  You don't want your site littered with "obvious crap".  Neither do I.  And I know we're inundated with it.  But when you put a post in that bucket that arguably might not belong there, when it's only "debatably, a piece of crap", it does tend to stifle that discussion.

Comment: @SteveCohen - I often scratch my head over a DV or vote to close without allowing much time for the OP to edit. On the flip side, regardless of whether I am the downvoter or just trying to explain why the question has been voted down, it's rare that the OP will respond kindly. Nearly always the response is defensive or downright rude. I happen to be a mod, and there's a process to changing the rules. Frequently, the newcomer won't invest 15 minutes to tour the site and see what fits. I lost the desire to see DV explanations after my first year here.

Comment: @SteveCohen My advice to "stop caring about magic Internet points" was general, not personal. It's just the one solution I know of that works. If you don't care about magic Internet points, well, good for you ;) You're one step closer to not letting anonymous downvotes bother you than I was when I started using SE.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer The expectation that anyone would spend 15 minutes on a tour is unreasonable, in my opinion. The Internet is full of TL;DR people. And SE is even optimized for quick questions, as there's not even a requirement to sign up. If it takes 15 minutes to understand what questions will fit and what won't, we've failed. (Fortunately, I don't think it takes that long. The main problem is just visibility of the rules. I didn't even know this code of conduct existed.)

Comment: @trlkly - you are right, 5 minutes should suffice. When I wrote 15, I was thinking of the multiple times we've had a new member whose first question was well off topic, and when we pointed that out, he proceeded to go to meta, and write a good 1000 words on why we should have virtually no criteria for appropriate questions. Then continued the debate in the comments. After a week of debate, never seem again. Of course, that's not exactly typical. To your point, the OT and COC need to be easily accessible on every board.