# How are Impact stats calculated?

Tags: support

The new profile theme includes *Impact* stats (~100k people reached). How is this calculated?

Is there any way to calculate this for sites which haven't been upgraded?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here