# Why is the number of people reached by Community account only ~612?

Tags: support, community-user, people-reached

On [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community), this automated account has voted 16k+ times, edited 338 posts and has 59 helpful flags besides announcing the results of elections. Yet, why is the Impact as low as 612?

Comment: On which site? Here on Meta.SE it has 0 people reached?

Comment: overflow.. How is it 0?

Comment: That high? Wow. Given the account doesn't post any questions or answers, how would it get **any** impact at all? (probably from transferred posts, that's how).

Comment: Are votes not counted in impact?

Comment: No, they are not. You can see how impact is derived at the post introducing it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here

Comment: Rather than a question, can we have a wiki article specifying how is impact calculated?

Comment: All we do is Q&A, we don't understand wikis.

Comment: But you do have community wiki..!!

Comment: @anshabhi But those are just questions, too. There's no need to bump a CW sticker under it. I think Community Wiki doesn't really do what you think it does.

Comment: The impact can easily be derived from the (automated) Election announcements attached to the account. Just add up the views of those posts (note that most of those have been migrated from Meta.SE so had higher views at some point).