# Can the People Reached measure be a little more accurate?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, people-reached

There are currently 219 users on the elementary OS site (36 per page, 6 full pages +3).

And yet, despite that my impact is ~808:

[image]

On any other site, this would be fine - external visitors. But as it is a private beta, there can't be more visitors than users. This calculation seems a little way off. 267% bigger than it should be in fact.

This makes me wonder just how inaccurate the measure on other sites is. Could this be sharpened up a little more, or is it meant to be really, really general?

If it is meant to be general, please could it be rounded to 1 or 2 significant figures?

~808 is fairly contradictory. Is it approximately, or exactly - because 808 is quite an "accurate" number.

Comment: FWIW, I never looked at this stat as *a number of people / users*. Just a number I'd like to grow. :)

Comment: In addition to what Oded have already said, neither private beta, nor any other site states doesn't certainly mean there's no outside visitors - even private beta can be visited by anyone who wants.

Comment: So you expected those "arbitrary impactness points" to make the slightest bit of sense?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> or is it meant to be really, really general?

It is meant to be really, really general.

Details can be found at [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

Comment: Would you consider making the number look less accurate?

Comment: You mean like putting a symbol that means "approximate number", like the tilde symbol (`~`)?

Comment: @Oded but it's already there?..

Comment: @nicael - it is? I must have put it there then.

Comment: I mean like rounding it, so it ends in a 0, not an 8 giving an impression of accuracy. I know it's not accurate, but they seem to contradict each other. "*Approx 265,157,891* people visited this site" is contradictory in the same way

Comment: @Tim - consider that as soon as it goes over 1000, it will get rounded.

Comment: @Tim Should they round it in base ten or binary?

Comment: @Tim the number is the accurate amount of total views. The "~" is there because it's not accurate regarding the "people reached" part itself, which is general, since nobody can tell if someone who viewed a question actually read it and/or all its answers.