# Difference between Profile Views and People reached

Tags: support, views, people-reached

My profile showing me, **~48k people reached** and **341 profile views**.

What's the difference between both?

Comment: Well, officially the difference between both is 47,659.

Comment: Well played, @JonW, well played

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Profile views** is the number of people that went to [your specific profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current).

**People Reached** is the approximate number of people that your posts have been seen by. (Although that's a *very* loose interpretation. There is more info on that here: "[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)").