# Massive change in 'People Reached' overnight

Tags: support, people-reached

On Stack Overflow, your profile page provides a facility to determine the impact of your questions and answers.

Yesterday it was showing 7k and right now it is showing 19k, so in single day it increased by 12k. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got an upvote yesterday on [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33623860/447356) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720089/how-to-use-shared-preferences-in-fragment-in-android) and as you can see, it got 12k views:

> [image]

So yes indeed, you reached 11,778 people in a split of a second. :)

Technically speaking, the upvote just caused your answer to become eligible, as described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here):

> - Answers - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
> - Non-deleted AND
>
>   - **Score > 0 AND**
>   - ...

Worth to mention, that it goes both ways... if you will get a downvote on that answer, or other answers will  get enough upvotes, that 12k will be reduced again from your impact. Unlike badges, this is a "live" stat.

Comment: i upvote other's answer  ,now it reduce to 10k from 22k..why?

Comment: @Aditya The last paragraph explains why your impact went down another 12k. _"Worth to mention, that it goes both ways... if you will get a downvote on that answer, **or other answers will get enough upvotes,** that 12k will be reduced again from your impact."_ You upvoted the other answers, so your answer is no longer in the top 3 answers on that question. (That exact part of the requirements isn't in this answer, but it is in the linked question with the requirements in it.) Basically, your answer became _ineligible_ again, so you lost that impact.

Comment: @Kendra just curious, how did you find this comment from the OP? Nothing here was bumped as far as I can tell. For the record, you're totally correct. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Looking through questions from the weekend. I found this one, and almost always read the comments if the chain is short enough. :) Edit: Actually, now I don't know how I found this- It was in my question list. xD Maybe I left a search up over the weekend. (Yup, it was a search on "people-reached" tag.)

Comment: @Kendra lol, fair enough. Thought I missed some secret feature or something. :-D

Comment: @Kendra and shadow thanks for clarfication