# Showing wrong impact count (people reached) 204k in my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, people-reached

On Database Administrator Stack Exchange I have given only one answer at that time the question was already viewed by more than 100K (approx) people then I have added my answer so the total impact count should be 104k (People reached ) right, but it showing as 204k in my [Profile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/41746/ali786).

So may I know how its being calculated and is it a expected behavior?

Answer (score 6):

In [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534) they explained the logic as:

> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> **Questions**
>
> - Non-deleted only
>
> **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
> - Non-deleted AND
> - Score > 0 AND
> - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>   - In the top 3 answers OR
>   - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>   - Score >= 5 OR
>   - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

So it is not consider the view count at the time of when you post the question. It is calculating as per today, if it meets the above condition.

Comment: Okay that is explained but it seems to be little inconsistent though the counting of answer will be on the parent question but it should start from the point at which I answered the question.