# How to get "people reached" info from Users Table?

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

How can I get "people reached" data from the Users table for Stack Overflow?

I didn't find any fields related to the people reached state in the Users table/schema.

Is it possible to get that data from the Users table or using `User_id`?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    Reputation
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    Location like '%Tamilnadu%'
ORDER BY
    Reputation DESC;
```

Comment: I believe this is calculated and cached, not stored - but I'll double check that.

Comment: Correct, it is a calculated value - not stored.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here - this has the details of how it is calculated.