# How to handle over-zealous moderators?

Tags: discussion, support

What kind of checks and balances are in place for over-zealous, puritan moderators who seem to have nothing better to do with their time than make it very difficult for people with genuine questions to get answers? Case in point- I was working on an answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/257395/34900) on GIS Stack Exchange, which I considered to be on-topic. The OP was asking a programming question related to prominent GIS software and features. Next thing I know, the question is put on hold as off-topic. Per the [Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) page:

> Keep the site ***reasonably*** on topic by closing, migrating, or removing
>   ***blatantly*** off-topic questions.

With as little reputation as I have, is there nothing I can do to help users like this escape the oppressiveness and get answers to their questions?

Comment: You should bring up complains with a specifc site on the per site meta: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/ and the community can vote to reopen, if they want to.

Comment: Each site has its own politics on top of Theory of moderation and the close reason for the question is quite clear: ""Questions relating to general IT or with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here ", simple python programming are really not specific...

Comment: I honestly don't see how that specific question is on-topic on GIS, except that their programming problem is in a GIS tool. They even have a specific close reason for it as they would probably be swamped otherwise with that kind of questions. Anyway, I pinged that mod to comment here.

Comment: @rene: I'm not sure I like the culture where moderators have to justify their actions in this way. They are burdened enough as it is.

Comment: @Bathsheba I take no as an answer but I don't like discussing stuff behind the back of people. If that adds to the burden, I apologize.

Comment: he is a regular here. he will come and clarify your doubt

Comment: I think the question given as an example is blatantly off-topic for [gis.se] where it was posted. I would expect that an answer to it would be quickly found at [so] and, if not, could be asked there.

Comment: @PolyGeo I apologize for calling you out like that. I let my emotions get the best of me and I obviously didn't handle it as I should have. It's just that I've been in the shoes of people like Chris- you join a question & answer site, build up the courage to ask your question, which shows inexperience and vulnerability, just to have the experts tell you you're doing it wrong. It can easily lead to people not wanting to ask more questions. Which is unfortunate, because I know how valuable sites like these are.

Comment: The reach of SE sites is incredible, and to get why that is so, and why our focus is so much on Q&A quality, a recommended reading is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here  We want as many users asking and answering quality questions as possible but to get that we are constantly teaching new users how to ask good questions, and cannot always handhold as much as we would if our users had unlimited time to volunteer.

Answer (score 11):

The moderators of graduated sites, like the one you cite, have been chosen by the respective community via a rigorous election. Various checks and balances are put in place which mean that anyone putting themselves up for election need to have a reasonable amount of experience on the relevant site.

Indeed nobody is perfect and occasionally poor decisions might have been made. But not in this case. I would not call this particular moderator over-zealous. Clearly this question is off topic for that site, and probably off topic for Stack Overflow too due to a lack of code showing the attempts made thus far. The question itself is little more than a code request.

Naturally you are at liberty to answer poor questions, but you do so at the hazard of potentially wasting your time.

Comment: Unimportant sidenote: With the majority of SE sites being beta, I think it's far more likely that a moderator was directly appointed by SE rather than elected by the community.

Comment: @yannis: The moderator in question has amassed a mid 5 figure reputation: no mean feat on a "sparse" site.

Comment: I was referring to your first paragraph, which I took to be a more general comment and not specifically about the moderator in question. Who, was indeed elected by the community (GIS is a graduate site).