# What's the formula for the "impact" figure on my user profile page?

Tags: support, profile-page, people-reached

How does Stack Overflow calculate the number "impacted", for the impact figure at the top of the user page on each site?

I know there's an explanatory comment, but it's kind of general and vague.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The calculation is explained in the [announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/162102) for the feature:

> That's how we got to the current method, which counts views on the following:
>
> - **Questions**
>
>   - Non-deleted only
> - **Answers** - Views of the parent question for answers that are:
>
>   - Non-deleted AND
>   - Score > 0 AND
>   - Also meets one or more of the following criteria:
>
>     - In the top 3 answers OR
>     - Is the Accepted Answer OR
>     - Score at least 5 OR
>     - Has at least 20% of the total vote count

See the announcement for more explanation of the rationale.

The number is approximate, not exact; it's probably heavily cached.  To sanity-check this (without having to wrangle tons of data), I looked at my own [profile](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/users/290/monica-cellio) on Health Meta, which shows:

- Impact: ~377
- Question views: 231
- Qualifying answer views: 37, 110

231 + 37 + 110 = 378.  Maybe I caused one of those view bumps while collecting this data.

Comment: So, you're saying the views for all such questions, and questions-with-answers, are added up?

Comment: @einpoklum yes, your "impact" number is the sum of all that for all your posts.