# why not let question authors remove "protected" designation?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, protected-questions

It seems that the moderators are too loose with the "protected" designation.  I've seen this with questions asked by others and I've had it done to my own questions.

I've seen a number of questions without any down-voted answers become "protected".  I do realize that some answers may have been removed, but it wasn't the case for at least some of the questions I asked. Which makes it impossible to answer for new users who just joined the communities where the questions were asked.

This is particularly impactful when it happen to questions in lightly-visited communities.  In such situations, a particular question may be interesting, but its author would never see many of potentially good answers which would be given by people joining these lightly-visited communities for the 1st time (often with the specific purpose of answering these questions).

Why not give the authors of questions ability to remove the "protected" designation?  Sort of as a "I can handle bad answers better than no answers" veto?

**Edit**

After considering the following point made in Catija's answer:

> Preventing the bad answers reduces the amount of work that the high-rep users and moderators have to do in order to clean up bad content. You don't get to make others to do this work because you want lots of answers or points of view.

I have to agree with not allowing authors absolute right to "unprotect" questions.  However, in the interest of making the community more helpful, as much as possible, rather than coming off censorial, I will propose a feature request as following:

How about giving authors ability to *privately* unprotect questions?  A *privately unprotected question* would mean that "new" users can post answers and they will not be seen by community until the authors gain enough reputation (similar to how this works with upvotes on certain questions right now)?  Question authors should, however, see all answers -- even the ones hidden from the community due to low reputation of those who answer them.  Answers which are not eligible to be seen by the community should not be eligible for moderation, either.  This should reduce the flow of low-quality answers in the direction of moderators.

Comment: So the author would be able to see these private answers but nobody else?  We as a community are not big on providing help to one individual.  So who will moderate, these private answers, that the community will be unable to moderate?  "even the ones hidden from the community" - Deleted answers are not hidden from the community, they can be seen, if you have enough reputation.  "Answers which are not eligible to be seen by the community should not be eligible for moderation" - Sounds like a way to turn SE into a discussion forum.  The changes to your proposal have made it even worst.

Comment: @Ramhound, You make a few points.  Everyone would see those answers once the person providing the answer gained a high-enough reputation to post answers to protected questions.  So it would not discourage contribution.  No one would moderate private answers other than the question poster. Remember that the question poster would have to elect to private-undel.  Once an answer poster gained enough rep, all of their previous private answers would become regular answers (eligible for regular moderation and eligible to be seen). Re: (everyone can see..) Maybe authors should always see (w/o re rep).

Comment: Please be careful with editing your question after it got answers and a status tag. If your edit invalidates existing answers, which your latest edit kind of does, we tend to rollback your edit. Now I'm pretty sure the status tag will not have to change as your amended question would still be status-declined but the answers  now only covers the earlier revision of your post. I have the feeling you better start a new request, maybe linking to this one for context.

Comment: @rene, I made it clear that the edit occurred by delineating it with the word "Edit" in bold.  Was that not careful?

Comment: No, not really because now all other answer authors have to revisit their post to validate if what they said still applies even with your new *take* to solve the issue at hand. What happens if they all bring up arguments against this new version, are you going to edit in a third? fourth? fifth? And if I vote on this feature request, which one will it be? The first one or the second one? What about the third one (that is bound to be added)? Can you see how this get messy? I understand you want to advocate your POV with an outcome in your favor but this tends to become unclear for everyone.

Comment: @rene, well, I would assume that I can modify the feature request until it is shaped into something useful to consider. I think the presense of the clear "Edit" label makes it unambiguous that some of the answers may have been made posted before the edit. I guess I can timestamp any future edits (which I currently have no plans of making). But the flip side of this is that some of the answer will continue to be relevant even after the edit.  Asking a new (slightly modified) question will only frustrate those who answered the original question (because they will feel they already addressed it).

Comment: @grovkin Adding "edit" to your post is just noise.  There's a revision history to keep track of what edits to a post were made, when, and by whom.  That doesn't make it any more appropriate to edit a question into a completely different question.  Sticking "edit" in your post doesn't make it okay to edit your question into a different question.  Edits are fine (great even) when they're improving *the question that you've been asking all along*.  But editing to *ask something different* isn't.

Answer (score 15):

No, this should not be implemented.

If you feel like a question of yours is wrongly protected, flag it and ask the moderators to unprotect the question or write a meta question on the child meta site asking that the protection be removed and explain why you are requesting this. If the moderator or community agrees, they will unprotect it. Note, this does not prevent the question from being protected again if the issues causing the protection in the first place continue after it being unprotected.

As a moderator, I find it frustrating that there's no option to set an expiration time for protected questions (the way there is for locked ones), so I'm often happy to unprotect a question if a few days or a week have passed given a reminder - particularly if a question was on the [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) list but has since fallen off and is unlikely to collect many new low-quality answers.

That said, no, I don't think that users should be able to unprotect their own questions unless they have the appropriate reputation to earn the privilege to do so. Users, particularly new ones, don't necessarily understand how Stack Exchange is designed to work and may fail to understand why the question was protected. Your very statement implies that you don't:

> Why not give the authors of questions ability to remove the "protected" designation? Sort of as a "I can handle bad answers better than no answers" veto?

You don't get to set the rules for "your" question. It must still follow the standards of the site. In that sense, it's the site's question. **You** aren't the one "handling" the bad answers (editing, downvoting, deleting), the site is. Preventing the bad answers reduces the amount of work that the high-rep users and moderators have to do in order to clean up bad content. You don't get to make others to do this work because you want lots of answers or points of view.

As I said in a comment, being able to unprotect ones own question is a conflict of interests. The OP wants answers and the site has decided that the question is attracting too many bad ones. While it's appropriate to ask for input from the community about whether the protection should stay in place, it's not appropriate for the OP to be able to unprotect their own questions.

Comment: The question is *mine* in as much as I am its author.  I thought that would have been clear from the context.

Comment: Once it's on the site, it's the site's question. You're merely the author. You do not get to set the rules for the question.

Comment: This meta question was tagged "feature-request".  I was asking for this particular ability.  At the very least, if removing of "protected" designation is gated by a certain rep requirement, shouldn't removing such a designation on one's own question require less rep?

Comment: My answer is explaining why this feature request should not be implemented and why it's unnecessary. I don't see why people are better judges of their own posts than of the posts of other users. I'd argue that, if anything, the conflict of interest should imply that users should be unable to unprotect their own questions entirely, regardless of reputation.

Comment: Because questions get "protected" after presumably "attracting poor quality answers".  I don't think I need to justify why the person asking a question is, at least somewhat, a better judge of that.  If someone asking a question finds that no good answers have been given (even if some answers have been upvoted), the moderators are not doing them any favors by removing ability from a larger community to provide new answers.

Comment: By the way, it is *NOT* the site's question.  The site is hosting the question, but contributions are licensed under Creative Commons.

Comment: @grovkin Might read the entire SE license surrounding submitted contributions

Comment: @grovkin (3 comments up) Yes, you do need to justify why you think the person asking a question is a better judge of poor quality answers than the people who are protecting it. Many readers of this question do not find it even slightly obvious why that should be the case, and in fact believe otherwise.

Comment: @Ramhound, are you suggesting that the content authors do not retain copyright?  According to the terms posted on each page, the content authors retain copyright but license it under Creative Commons to the site.  Which still makes these contributions respective "authors' questions/answers/comments."

Comment: @grovkin - If you have licensed the contribution to the site, the site has rights to the contribution also, as the author you don't have complete and total control over the contribution

Comment: @Ramhound, I never claimed to have total control to what happens on the site.  In fact, I stipulated that the site is hosting the content.  This alone gives it the right to limit which content is hosted.  I was merely responding to the claim that "it's the site's question".  And complains about biased moderation are frequent enough on skeptics/law/politics child sites.  In fact they are so frequent and come from so many reputable contributors that I have no reason to think that the opinion that this is a two-way street is exclusive to me.

Comment: @grovkin - You seem to have a bias against moderation.  I am guessing, don't take part, in the community moderation.  You have more then enough reputation at both those sites and be involved, if you see a protected question that shouldn't be protected, you should flag to open it (and vice-versa)

Comment: @Ramhound, I don't have a bias against moderation as such.  I am against moderators using procedure to suppress quality content in order shape narrative to match their own worldview.  As I mentioned, the bias towards view-shaping (as opposed to content quality-control) is more common on the less-technical sites.  And this opinion is often voiced by reputable contributors.

Comment: @grovkin I *moderate* one of the most subjective/non-technical sites on this network and I've already admitted that I'm happy to reconsider the protected status on just about any question because I don't like the current mechanics of it. I don't really appreciate the insinuation that the moderators are somehow the ones at fault when you haven't even tried (as far as I'm aware) to request that the protected status be removed. Give the moderators a change to explain... assume good intent. I reworded the part where I stated that it's the site's question to explain and clarify that point.

Comment: I mean... @grovkin if you even bothered to look at the [Politics Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/preemptively-protecting-hot-network-questions) you'd see exactly this same thing happening - someone asks about a question being protected, a mod agrees that it's no longer necessary and removes it. That is the second question from the top on their meta (by recent activity)! Your concerns are noted but seem to be misplaced.

Comment: @grovkin - Except you are one of those reputable contributors.  Do you flag for a question to be unprotected, when you feel, it shouldn't be protected?  Do you improve questions when they need to be improved?  Do you participate in community moderation or are you just one that says there is a problem?

Comment: @Ramhound, I have edited others' questions and I have done a few reviews.  Like I said, I am not against moderation as a tool for improving quality of content.  I am also not for removing the "protected" designation as such.  My request was very narrow and I even agreed that it may need to be narrowed further (only allow such privelege to question authors with high enough rep, for example).  Maybe it would help to allow question authors to see all answers (even deleted ones) before making the decision to unprotect or for a reasonable period of time after they are deleted.

Comment: You have yet to reach the reputation, that allows you see the type of answers, that are routinely deleted.  I can guarantee you, if you had that reputation, you wouldn't want to place that suffering on anyone's shoulders.

Comment: @Ramhound, I take your point and I carefully considered that particular point in this answer.  I modified my request somewhat to take it into account.

Answer (score 10):

Cause authors sometimes have too much skin in the game - you have an *emotive* attachment to your post, and would, more likely than not, request to have it unprotected.

Protection is, pretty mild. It keeps people without a certain minimal reputation from answering. That's about it. Being able to trivially remove this, kind of turns it from mild to toothless.

If there's no answers at *all* as opposed to many deleted bad answers, there's no need to protect. If there's many bad answers, the system, or even high reputation users can protect it to help maintain overall quality.

If you actually want protection removed, making a post making a case for it on your site meta, asking a mod on chat or even flagging would work.

Comment: Well, now we are getting into details.  What if there are no removed answers? Or what if there are no removed answers other than answers removed by their authors? I do understand that egos can motivate question authors to overlook the fact that they may be attracting trully defacing answers, but if a question merits an answer (it's not off topic, it's not duplicate, poorly worded, etc.), I think it's OK for the author to have skin in the game because, if nothing else, they can't figure out where to get an answer to their question.

Comment: so flag it. Or post on meta. And you're basically *only* losing out people with almost no reputation on the site - and in some cases, I've seen people on other sites ask for protection to be lifted so they can answer.

Comment: Well, as someone who asked a question and who used the site for a while, I know that the meta site is available.  But the smaller communities' meta sites are so contentuous that I am generally discouraged to use them. Certainly, anyone asking a question for the 1st time would be less likely to try to figure out how to challenge any limitation on it after seeing something which *seems* like shut down of a question.   It's also questionable that asking moderators to overturn moderators' decisions is a process that does not touch on egos.

Comment: While it may be tautological and maybe somewhat self-serving.  Just look at the votes on this particual meta question itself.  It attracts immediate knee-jerk downvoting even though it's a perfectly innocent question about how to control quality of question authors' experience on the site.  It pits moderators against question authors so the more experienced users of the site (let's say the "orthodoxy") knee-jerk against it.  But this discourages participation.  Yet the most frequent advice given is to engage with such orthodoxy on child sites in order to correct it.  It's not constructive.

Comment: @grovkin If you had asked the support or discussion question "What can I do if I think my question had been protected incorrectly?" The question would have been received quite differently than it was. As a Feature Request, the way users show whether they agree with the request or not is with voting. Down votes on feature requests are used to show disagreement with the post.

Answer (score 2):

I see new users trying to use Stack Exchange sites as discussion forums frequently, and any writing of bad answers by them is a prime reason for having protected questions. To give the askers of those questions the ability to remove the protection that experienced users with the privilege to set protection and a site's moderators (elected on all but Beta sites) have deemed appropriate, would be highly undesirable.

If the askers of questions that attract bad answers, and the providers of bad answers, were to read the **You gotta get this to get us** paragraph from [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534) then I think they would have a much better appreciation that the impact of bad answers is not only on the asker, but also on anyone from the community, or just visitors to the site, who is looking for an answer to that question, at any time in the future.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are not answering my specific question.  I did not ask for "protected" designation to be removed.  I asked why can't the questions' authors have that privilege.

Comment: @grovkin I think that I already was, but I have now made my answer even more specific to your question.