# Should the community adopt the company's goals for these sites or follow their own?

Tags: discussion

The aim of Stack Exchange, Inc. (the company), as Joel Spolsky has expressed it, is [monetarization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY). For many users of the sites, one of their aims – besides procrastination and playing the game of gaining virtual repuation – is getting (and providing) information. That is, the goal is getting an answer to a question that we have, or to help someone else get their answer.

I have often been in conflict between providing the best answer and following the site rules. From my experience, the site rules (and SE Inc's monetarization goal) can stand in the way of providing quick useful help.

From a user perspective, why should I adopt the company goal? Why isn't it better for us as a comunity as seekers and providers of information to disregard the company's interests and do what best serves the goal of providing information?

---

Some examples for where the viewpoints of SE Inc. and the community might diverge:

- Offsite links

  Sometimes the best answer is an edit to a Wikipedia article and a link to it. Stealing content from another site is both illegal and immoral.

  Offsite content such as scientific journals may also be more stable and permanent than Stack Exchange itself. The claim that only SE will be able to provide permanence on the internet is presumptuous (and probably driven by the company's interest).

  A link may also be a means for a user to find a better answer on another site. A short summary here of a long post elsewhere may not be the best answer. In that case, a link is.
- Questions can only have one best answer

  For many questions there are many equally good answers. For example, the best approach to solving a parenting or writing problem will often depend on individual factors such as the personality of the person asking the question.
- Duplicate questions

  The more often a question has been asked and answered, the more likely it is that someone using a search engine will find one of those answers. Finding an answer when one doesn't know the appropriate technical terms or how a duplicate question has been phrased is often next to impossible. The more often a question has been asked and answered, the more likely it is that the way one individual asker searches for the answer returns a search engine result.

---

*Note.*

Jeff Atwood's [expressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) goal, when he co-created these sites, was "helping all the people who will ever have that problem to find the best answers". It is my impression that after Jeff has left, Joel has begun to follow a different goal.

Comment: -1 for *"if the best answer is off-site, then a link should be the answer."* No. Not in any site. Links may break if the off-site content gets offline. Link-only answers can be deleted with just a few votes in that direction, for good reason.

Comment: *From that viewpoint SEO is important* ... Their main source of income is Jobs, SE Enterprise and SO Teams. None of those require SEO.

Comment: @Renan What makes you believe that links to, say, scientific journals are less permanent than Stack Exchange? What makes SE more permanent than the rest of the internet? What if SE disappears? You are looking at this from SE Inc's point of view, not from the point of view of a person who seeks information and for whom SE (the sites) are just one site on the net among billions that are no more likely to survive than one of the others. The basic concept of the internet was to make information flow more stable by avoiding having all info collected in one place. Monopolies are a danger.

Comment: *the SEO of SO serves as advertising for SE's enterprise products.* ... then I wonder what those sales people are doing all day ....

Comment: Your premise is flawed. The site rules are not related to monetisation (quite the opposite, in some of your now-deleted examples - trawling through unclosed duplicates in search of the canonical answers is *more* page views). If you are in conflict with them, you can't blame that on the company's goals.

Comment: You may find it helpful to read the following on duplicates https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ and link-only "answers" https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/248731

Answer (score 12):

Generally the rules have evolved based on experience. We need to

1. Create something that has high quality Q&A otherwise it isn't much use to anyone searching for answers.
2. Create something where answerers want to continue to participate. Having to repeat yourself hunderds of times gets boring.
3. Balance the needs of askers, answerers, moderators and passing viewers.

> answering a question multiple times doesn't hurt the asker nor the answerer

It makes keeping things up to date when there are changes harder. If we need to do that should add a single new answer to the canonical question or hundreds of new answers all over the place?

> sometimes there are more than one good answer to a question

No problem writing multiple answers with different options. They can all be voted on.

You've now got more than one answer to this question. They aren't identical even though they posit similar views in places. It's certainly useful to me to read someone else's views on this question other than just mine and given the voting so far, it looks like both answers have value.

> if the best answer is off-site, then a link should be the answer (instead of stealing the content)

And when that site stops working or changes so the link is no longer valid, what is that answer worth any more? How would we keep track of external changes if we did that for every answer?

Links to external sites are OK as long as the answer works without that link. I.e. links should provide additional reading if you want to know more but visiting them should not be required.

Answer (score 5):

(Many quotes in this answer refer to the [original version of this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/340830/1))

Practically - *most* of these rules were worked out by individual communities. There was a lot of care and engagement between folks in the company and the community in the early days - and unsurprisingly enough, these things worked really well.

*If* there's a need to adjust a specific norm per community, its worth discussing there.

> duplicate questions must be removed

Or rather duplication makes finding stuff difficult. The goal of dupe closures is ostensibly to act as signposts to a canonical answer.

> questions should have one best answer

Which serves as a useful starting point for someone *seeking* answers.

> links to external answers must be removed

Because self contained answers have value. If a link goes bust, the answer is useless and we may end up wasting time clearing up after the fact. The [Wisdom of the Ancients](https://xkcd.com/979/) must be preserved

> answering a question multiple times doesn't hurt the asker nor the answerer

It causes clutter. A *few* sites - like SR.SE found that separate answers worked for them, but on the whole, edits usually work better.

Many communities *really* would not like this.

It works well for SR.SE since each answer is about a *product* and the multiple answers actually added value to the site.

> sometimes there are more than one good answer to a question

There is more than one way to solve a problem, sure but its always nice if folks try to make theirs the best way. While that green tick means a bit more, an earnest seeker of truth is likely to look at the other answers if one dosen't work.

> if the best answer is off-site, then a link should be the answer (instead of stealing the content)

We don't steal. We have rules against plagiarism. We *paraphrase* and *attribute* at least. We pull together multiple sources and *synthesise* at our best. A link only answer can lack context, and as said above, may be lost to time if the original source goes down. In addition - fuller answers encourages folks to build on the original source.

In some cases - we might find answers from sources not easily shareable. I have an old answer that was based of a local LUG mailing list mail.

> and so on

And so forth.

> I have often been in conflict between providing the best answer and following the site rules. More often than not the site rules (and SE Inc's viewpoint) stand in the way of providing quick useful help.

And yet these rules have served us well in better days than these, and build up things to where they are now. Probably not worth throwing out the baby, and the tub with the bathwater.

> From a user perspective, why should I adopt the company goal? Why isn't it better for us as a comunity as seekers and providers of information to disregard the company's interests and do what is best for us?

Because in many ways these interests can align. That *quality* is something many communities have taken pride in - and quite frankly a good chunk of these started with the community, and were discussed here and per site metas.

That those goals alight is a *desirable* outcome, IMO - though to an extent that needs both sides to work out some differences these days

While its in OP's comment

> What makes you believe that links to, say, scientific journals are less permanent than Stack Exchange? What makes SE more permanent than the rest of the internet? What if SE disappears?

SE has data dumps that could seed a new site. While there's a few wrinkles (like images) - a self contained answer has more potential value *post network* - either in a data dump, something like Archive Team's rescue efforts or even Way back machine backups. The usefulness of quality content can *outlast* the network. A good QA set has value as an artifact in its own right.

> Jeff Atwood's expressed goal, when he co-created these sites, was "helping all the people who will ever have that problem to find the best answers". It is my impression that after Jeff has left, Joel has begun to follow a different goal.

And yet many of the norms questioned are from *Jeff's* time as CEO. And are aimed at well - helping people find the best answers.

Most of us don't begrudge the company's attempts to make money - just the fallout from when they fail.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to:

> More often than not the site rules (and SE Inc's viewpoint) stand in
>   the way of providing quick useful help.

if you have not already seen it, I think understanding the Stack Exchange network, and the way it works, falls into place by reading the section titled **You gotta get this to get us** at [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).

In particular I think the site protocols are as they are because:

> ... they're about helping *all the people who will **ever** have that
>   problem to find the best answers*. And find 'em instant-like.

As best I can tell those protocols evolved around ideas from Jeff Atwood (one of Stack Overflow's founders) and in partnership between SE communities and SO staff.

Comment: If I adopt the goal of "helping all the people who will ever have that problem" (and I do!) the best answer to a question is sometimes to edit a Wikipedia article and link to it instead of writing an answer here.

Comment: Following a link is not instant-like.  It's once removed and may be broken.

Answer (score 1):

From a very general point of view (but I think that it really applies here): The company should do what the company wants to do and the community, i.e. all the users, should do what they want to do within the rules that the company imposes because the users are on there premises of the company. It's really as simple as that.

The goals of the company and of the users can never be exactly identical, but following the rules, aka the code of conduct, is the minimum that every user has to do in order to continue to participate on this site.

Beyond that there is quite some room for doing things differently. Ask good questions or ask mediocre questions, answer with long and thorough answers, answer with short and quick answers, or just comment. It's up to you really. I would expect of everyone that he or she is maximizing his or her own fun here within the bounds of the code of conduct. Do what you want to do!

I basically estimated what the company's likely future vision is and what I would like it to be and the amount of overlap basically determines how much time I will invest. I guess that everyone makes similar estimations.