# How multiple answers by one user on same question impact on People Reached

Tags: support, answers, people-reached

**EDIT**

[We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) discuss the

Big Question #1: Do you have any suggested tweaks to improve the calculation method?

Big Question #2: What's a better name?

#### Nothing mentioned about How multiple answers by one user on same question impact on People Reached

---

We have [the formula](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320520/10961238) to calculate the People Reached. Now consider a question with *x views* and a user has two valid answers (can be two different approaches)
Let's say currently the user has *10,000 people reached*. So what will be people reached after both answers meet the formula? Will, it is *10,000 + x or 10,000 + 2x*.

- *10,000 + x* will include only x views even both answers meet the formula
- *10,000 + 2x* will include only 2x views as both answers meet the formula

If it is 2x then it might result in incorrect reached for highly viewed questions.

Questions with multiple answers by the same user might be less likely posted but I just want to know how it will affect people reached?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

Comment: I agree with the OP, not a duplicate.

Comment: The suggested duplicate goes to great lengths to explain exactly what is being asked, we can say no more than that.

Comment: @Rob The whole point of that question is to ask for feedback to establish better practices, the question as-such states current practices (as of 2014). There has been no statement as to which suggestions were or were not adopted or acted upon in some way. Have you read the edit history of the question, no substantial changes have been made since 2014 - just slight phrasing corrections. *Nothing I have stated is opinion - it is fact.* Whilst I'm confident that the OP of that question deserves respect, I'm not the slightest bit interested in ad hominem support or attacks, just this question now.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. There are [differences on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/282094) regarding closing for a duplicate. While no one appreciates 3rd party communication with the reviewers I understand that you thought that the automatically generated comment was open for you to reply to - no harm done, the wording isn't exclusive of that and it is being revised. Simply **use the Contact link** at the bottom of the page to object to the review.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, you'll notice that I didn't ping you in my first comment as it was intended to be read by other potential reviewers, ie. what you seem to be understanding about my motivation is based on a set of quite false assumptions which you could confirm as false if you read the order of your recent inbox messages. Personally, I've never minded my reviews being challenged, this is after all a democracy. You may feel differently about that though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many answers you have on a question. The given query uses the UNION clause to find Id's of the questions. The UNION will return an id only once. Even if that wasn't the case, the query that select the eligible questions for your people reached stat uses an IN clause. That will also guarantee a question will be included once.

This makes sense. The only relevant data point are question as only those carry a viewcount value, which is the primary input for the sum to your people reached statistic.

You can stop providing multiple answers to high viewed questions to improve your people reached stat. It will have no effect once you have one answer that qualifies the question to be included in your people reached stat.