# Does this answer your question? Notice remains open even after submitting feedback

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, questions, duplicate-suggestions

I have [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342473/484288) today and one member was voted as duplicate and private feedback was there, I choose *no* and submitted the form. When I revisit the question or refresh the page same notice *reappears* with yes/no options. 
In-network tab I got `200 OK` status and response as `"success":true`

Environment:
OS: Windows 10
Browser: Chrome 79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

From the comments, the same issue is happing with [area51.meta.stackexchange.com](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) [scifi.stackexchange.com](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) <sub>(might be with whole StackExchange network)</sub>

[image: Notice]

[image: GIF]

From network tab

[image: Headers]

[image: Response]

Comment: A similar thing happened to me [here](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29986/would-a-general-languages-se-site-be-feasible).  When I reload the page it comes back.

Comment: [Same for me over on SF&F](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12900/75000)

Comment: @YaakovEllis Similar [complaint on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392983/3648282).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was a bug with this component where it only worked part of the time. It should now work in all cases. I have also added functionality to it to delete the "is this a duplicate" comment that is associated with the rejected flag(s).