# Don't show "Does this answer your question" dialog again when another duplicate flag/vote (for the same original) is cast

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

When a user flags/votes to close your question as a duplicate, you'll see a dialog asking you to confirm whether it's a duplicate or not.

[image]

When you submit 'No', the dialog disappears, which is great. It is even hidden the next times you visit the question ... until another user flags/votes to close the question as a duplicate. Then it reappears; while that would make sense if a user proposes a *new* original, it is shown even when the *same* original is selected.

I don't like having to tell the system twice that I don't think it's a duplicate. I know I can just ignore the dialog, it will go away eventually, but it's still rather awkward.

<sub>Interestingly enough, if the duplicate flag/vote is retracted, the dialog disappears...</sub>

Comment: Similar: ["Does this answer your question?" Notice remains open even after submitting feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342500/282094).

Comment: @Rob not similar at all, but yeah, remotely related.