# Why isn't there a counter for answers (like there is for questions) saying "viewed ## times"?

Tags: feature-request, answers, views

I noticed that for questions there is a header saying "*Viewed n times*", but why isn't there a corresponding header for answers?

Comment: Because there is no way to differentiate someone viewing a question from someone viewing an answer if they are on the same page?

Comment: question & answers, all are in one page ...  I think SE count page view.. . `Viewed n times`... not question...

Comment: @ColleenV well, in theory the amount of times a share link was clicked can be counted, but of course it won't be any good, as most answer "views" come from people who reach the question first.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Yes, I thought about expanding my comment to include that, but the views on a question are not the same thing as the times the link was shared. If I had been writing an answer I might have elaborated :)

Comment: @ColleenV I mean share links of answers only, the URL contains the answer ID, so the code responsible for redirecting the user to the question and focusing on the answer can, in theory, also log that somewhere and call it "answer view".

Comment: @ShadowWizardisVaccinating Yes, but that number does not measure the same thing that the OP is asking about. It measures something different that could also be measured for the question and displayed.

Comment: Sha & ColleenV, it's possible to measure the scroll position and determine which portion of the page is visible; where more than one answer is visible the view count could be split - not that we need that, nor that it answers the question, just that it's not only possible but done elsewhere.

Comment: Why the down-vote? The question may lack understanding, but that's what questions are for, right?

Comment: There is a [people reached statistic for answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/282094), but along with the caveats mentioned there there's [other shortcomings](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342483/282094). The server logs do hold some information regarding URLs pointing directly to comments and answers; but such data isn't available to users, but is to staff.

Comment: @U.Windl On meta, downvotes can indicate rejection of an idea. In this case, the downvotes probably mean “we *should not* have a view counter for answers”.

Answer (score 10):

Because the system only logs how often a page is *loaded* (and does so [rather crudely](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90187/295232)), not how often a specific section of the page was *viewed*. It has no way of determining if a user viewed a specific answer. Technically, it also cannot tell whether you viewed the question or merely skipped it and started reading the answers, but IMHO it's not a bad assumption.

Comment: I agree, but as long as a question has no answer the count is clearly counting views of the question ;-)

Comment: Also, excluding the case where a user scrolls from the question to answers, the web server might consider the URL. Specifically considering the case when the user found the answer (link to it) via some Google search result.

Comment: So if the counter actually counts "page visits" (i.e.: question and any answer), why not move the counter above the summary, adding "page " in front, so that it reads "Page visited ## times"?

Answer (score -3):

I think they should provide a botton which says "view more" on each answer so as to know the people who are interested and click in that particular answer to enable us know how many people we help with the answers we provide.

Comment: -1 This idea is: (1) Not necessary. We can already measure how helpful answers are through votes and comments. These are not perfect, but nor are view counts. Actually, view counts are probably even *less* useful. (2) Harmful. It makes it harder to read all the answers.