# Do edits increase the number of people reached by a user?

Tags: support, edits, people-reached

Let's say I edited some questions and answers which required edits. Do the new visits, from then on, increase **MY** (the editor) impact (i.e., the number of people reached)?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated

Comment: but thats doesnt say about edits

Comment: "but thats doesnt say about edits" I know, that is why it is related and not an answer to your question.

Comment: @RobertLongson 'Editors' impact?

Comment: It's not technically possible since there is no monitoring of views except their amount. It's impossible to know amount of views based on time, so no way to tell the views after a certain edit. If and when views will be monitored better, with time stamp of each view, requests like this one would become possible. Until then... No way.

Comment: Thats right, maybe you can add that as an answer @ShadowWizardisEarForYou ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not the OP of the question or one of the answers then no, editing does not affect your own impact. Impact only comes from your questions and answers. If you do a good edit the change in impact will go to the [question asker and the answer providers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290491/what-does-people-reached-signify-and-how-is-it-calculated).

Note that all the system captures is the total number of views for a question, it does not capture timestamps for those views so if you create a new qualifying answer to an old highly impactful question you'd get the benefit of all that question's impact despite your answer only existing for a fraction of that question's life and the likelihood that almost all of the viewers have not seen your answer.

If it is your question or answer, however...

#### Short term

It might, edits bump the question so anyone looking for active questions might view that question or its answers to see why it's been edited and thereby increase its impact.

#### Longer term

A good edit might make the question easier to find, so more people looking for an answer to that issue might come across it.

And an edit could result in an answer getting more upvotes such that it now qualifies as impactful where it didn't before then.