# Is there a way to know the number of people's view after it exceeds 1k?

Tags: discussion

I found after people's view reach 1K, it always shows 1K in the SOF account dashboard and doesn't change again, probably until 2k. Is there a way to still see exactly how many people viewed my Q&A？

[image: Image showing the user's impact at 1k]

Comment: It's an estimate. Don't put too much faith in the exact value.

Comment: Yeah, true. But it is always a positive feedback and actually very encouraging to see how many people those posts impacted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The formula in estimating the number of people reached can be found in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here).

**There is a SEDE query that you can use to calculate the estimated number of "people reached": https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/253267/people-helped-public-prototype-1**

Take, for example, my Stack Overflow profile:

- profile shows 232k people reached
- SEDE query shows 232442 people reached

Note that the [data from SEDE updates once per week](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).

> How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?

> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Dec 13 at 9:59.

Comment: Thanks for this insight and help. I'll try to use this way to caculate the number.

Comment: BTW,  other than SEDE, Is there a more straightforward way to see the number? thanks

Comment: @Zinna You’re welcome! That should be the only way.

Comment: could you please let me know where I can find the userID for this query? thanks a lot!

Comment: It’s in the link to your profile. For Meta.SE, your ID is “878923”, as seen from your link https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/878923/zinna.

Comment: how come I saw the people'view on my profile is already 2K, but by using the query, it's only something like 1500? thanks

Comment: @Zinna Both are correct. The number shown on your profile is rounded off. So, `1500` would (correctly) appear as `2k` on your profile.

Comment: Got it , thanks Panda