# If you answer your own question will you be credited once or twice for the "people reached" statistics in your profile?

Tags: support, profile-page, self-answer, people-reached

I found [an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320520/807417) explaining how the "people reached" statistics is populated in the Stats box in the Profile tab.  Basically, if your answer qualifies, you will be credited the # of views of the question.

My question is in the scenario where **you answer your own question** and that your answer qualifies to be counted.  Will you be credited

- **twice**: once for posting the question, and once for posting the answer, or
- **once**: because the answer is for the question that you have been credited?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11754921/%d0%90%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%9a%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%86%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9) whose only contribution is a self-answered question (with a positively scoring answer) with (as I'm writing this) 30 views, and a 'people reached' value of 30. That would suggest the second option: you're only credited once for a question with a qualifying self-answer.

Answer (score 7):

It would appear that you are credited once.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58136285/remote-debugging-of-openshift-application-in-intellij-idea/58164409#58164409) has 2k views, and is self-answered (the self answer has more than 20% of the votes, and is therefore eligible). The person who posted this q&a pair has these two posts as their only two posts. They also have 2k reached in their profile. This means they are credited once.

Disclaimer: my numbers might be off because of caching, making this answer invalid.

Comment: Great idea to pick that example. Your approach is the same with Glorfindel.  Since the example is old enough (2 years), the statistics should no longer be in flux. It's recent enough that the calculation should be based on the latest rules. There is also no recent question / answer by the user that could have interfered with the calculation.