# My people reached count decreased from 250k to 11k

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, people-reached

I have used Stack Overflow for the last two months. One week ago, I had a 250k "people reached" count shown on my profile. Suddenly, it decreased and it shows 11k people reached. I don't know how this happened.

Did I do something wrong, or why has my people reached count decreased?

Comment: You're not the user specified in those links, so you will see nothing on them. Robert Longson already stated that they only work for the OP and mods. Use your own site user ID if you want to use that tooling for yourself. @MaikLowrey

Comment: @Nij ok. thanks for feedback.

Comment: See: [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/282094) - 11K is incorrect, but [this isn't 224K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523980/3648282) because of the secondary criteria, + your other posts  don't add up to that much.

Comment: my one post is delete but I have 240k people reached before that post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost certainly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48893935/how-can-i-remove-the-flutter-debug-banner/70523980#70523980) had a score of 5 at one time but then one of those 5 voter's accounts was deleted taking their vote with it and reducing your answer to its current score so that question's views don't count for you any more.

You can see in your reputation history a [reversal entry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16974425/dipak-ramoliya?tab=reputation&sort=time) on January 12th where you lost 70 points, most likely 7 upvotes.

See the [people reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) post for why a score of 5 is significant here and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320520/1038015) that says explicitly

> Specially if you have an answer that is around a score of 5 on a highly viewed question will result in big jumps in that number with single up- or down vote.

Comment: thanks for your reply now I have my answer but I have one confusion is it wrong to give right answer or helping other on this platform? and how to know all this?

Comment: Answering is not wrong, of course, but upvoting a bunch of answers only because a specific person wrote them is. That's why it was reversed.

Comment: okay @Glofindel thanks for your answer and  I not repeat this type of mistake.

Comment: you reverse my question @Golfindel?

Comment: Looks like someone upvoted that answer today, which brought the score back to 5 and the "people reached" value to 235k.