# What does the "reached" property mean on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-exchange, people-reached

If you go on [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6824121/lenny4?tab=profile) you will see that I have "reached" 703k:

[image]

First I thought it was the number of persons who:

- saw an answer of me
- saw a question of me
- or an edit I made on a question

and so on.

But, for example, [Daniel Widdis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1161484/daniel-widdis) has far more answers and questions than me:

[image]

And he only has "reached" 543k.

What does the "reached" property mean on Stack Exchange?

Comment: The vast majority of that number for you comes from [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59363755), the question has 500k views. On second place is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71178128) where the question has 127k views. On third place is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65056367)  where the question has 54k views. These three account for ~680k of your 703k reached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the amount of people you've 'reached' with your posts. Hovering over the statistic gives you a helpful pop-up, that also explains the way things are counted:

[image]

As [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWVvC.png) from the answer to the [old question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244534/were-working-on-a-new-stat-to-help-convey-the-reach-of-your-posts-here) linked in the comment section illustrates, the field used to have a name that was a bit more descriptive, but it is still the same field.

Comment: Transcribed: *"Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on page views of your questions and questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers)"*