# Different standards of conduct on different Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, comment-flags, answers-as-comments

I want to know clearly, if diversity in the working standard of good and bad conduct across different sites should be flexibly allowed or if we should have the same standard of defining good and bad conduct and ethos culture across platforms. Yes or no? I'm being neither sarcastic nor snide.

I go to one site, they want quick, curt answers. Another site uses longer sentences, complains about curt answers, and orbits the topic at a distance that wouldn't be accepted elsewhere. I've personally noticed this between ELU vs SO, SF, and UL. Users on the dev sites generally all tend to recognize not reading questions carefully and answering in threads, but no on ELU.

What should I expect from other sites? Personally, I'm in favor of giving ELU *and other sites* a longer leash, but I want to know what the community thinks about this? We're all different.

I'm new. This is my first question. I've asked this many different ways. Would someone please tell me directly, whether different interpretations of conduct should be tolerated across network sites?

Comment: The more I see this difference, the more I think: "This seems to be living-up to a stereotype that academics are 'know-it-alls'. So many hyper-confident answers that are factually incorrect. Some forums want that, others quickly reject it." Please, honestly tell me if it's okay to discuss whether we can decide if a culture has an arrogance beyond SE needs to stop at the door when coming into SE. If I'm wrong, please show me where and I'll concede.

Comment: The Stack Exchange network has Q&A sites. They are not designed to be forums.

Comment: Okay, Q & A sites, not forums. Can you please address the substance of the question by provitind a yes or no answer?

Comment: I'll just put my 2c for the discussion on the Meta ELU: most of the regular users on the meta never face the issue you faced because it's a one-time case (happens only when they haven't had any badges on the meta), so and your comments didn't really help clarifying it. On the other hand, you could have included a screenshot to demonstrate the issue easily.

Comment: Hey! You should not read ill intention unless the comments are actually offensive, aggressive in tone or obviously sarcastic. For example, I chose to ignore your reply on meta `You have not misibterpreted, but misread. Please reread the very last independent clause of the main paragraph` as being quite catty. It was, wasn't it? Never mind, let's start afresh.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I never claimed ill intent nor do I think it. My original did answer your question.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it back, removing all that clarification stuff people wanted. TY. Then you can remove your down vote.

Comment: Done, please read and I really want your answer @RobertColumbia.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like all of the comments you've mentioned are on your own posts, so the solution, in general, is that you should flag the ones you find "unfriendly or unkind" as... well... exactly that. (When you get 15 rep on a site, you can flag any comment there.) The flag menu is accessed by clicking the flag icon next to the comment you want to flag, but it can take some time for the flag to be acted upon because flags usually must be processed by moderators. If a moderator agrees with your flag they have two options: delete the comment or (if part of the comment is worth saving) edit out the bad part.

This process is the same for every single site.

It's a little unfair to blame the community at large though for this since it's a holiday and I suspect most people were out doing stuff (that's where *I* was at least; on any other day I would be lying in wait for posts on English). Plus the comments contained useful information, which is most likely why they were upvoted.

Comment: Thank you for this. I already know some, much helps me get the overall culture. And, I don't blame the whole community. Should I edit my question to avoid placing community-wide blame, but still ask.

Comment: @JesseSteele Yeah, saying things like "Really, English experts?" kinda sorta creates bad feelings where there didn't have to be any. A good rule to follow is: "assume good intentions" (a line so widely applicable I don't care it's from a [previous code of conduct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240839/323179), before it was even called one).

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it to be more respectful, but worse comments were tolerated on the example site. I agree with your critique of my wording, my bad. But, you called me out. Others' similar language wasn't called out on that one site. Is that difference right for me/us to accept from one site to another—my original question.

Comment: [Most of us are ***not*** on a holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_(United_States)).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, that's great! I am so thankful. Can I please get a yes or no to my yes/no question, pretty please?

Comment: @JesseSteele: When you ask a yes/no question, you can get a yes/no answer. At present, your question is far too complicated to be summed up with a one-word reply. Either one would be misleading or inappropriate.

Comment: @NicolBolas I made it more concise. Could you offer an answer with that?

Comment: @JesseSteele: Well, the question is closed, so the point is moot. But it's still a complex enough topic for yes/no to be appropriate answers. And furthermore, it's hard to even call it a "question" at this point since you provide what you consider to be an answer *before even asking the question*. At this point, it's clearly a full-on rant, due to what you feel is personal mistreatment you received on ELU, rather than any actual problem. Go take it up on ELU's meta.

Comment: Well, I do have my answer now, as edited, though it came as clearly and informally as the policy.

Comment: @JesseSteele: You have the answer you want. That doesn't mean it's the actual answer to your inquiry.

Comment: Feel free to answer differently, I'm open and waiting. I don't "want" either answer in particular. But, so far the evident answer is "yes". Please change it if you want. Upvote, request it be re-opened. Tell me what you think here.