# Are the blog goals for the next year just repeating our goals for this year?

Tags: discussion, welcoming, blog

The [current blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/) talks about

> big goals for the year ahead. We want to make Stack Overflow more diverse, inclusive, and welcoming.

Isn't it 2019 with 2020 in sight? Weren't being "diverse", "inclusive" and "welcoming" the goals of the *last* 12+ months?

**Edit:**  I remember that in spring 2018 this was [*the* topic](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/). Well, maybe being more "welcoming" is harder than it was thought to be and takes more time than 15 months.

I only wish '*preventing bad questions from being asked*' would be on this list of "big goals".

Comment: To quote Clifton, [one of the commenters on the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/24/announcing-stack-overflows-new-ceo-prashanth-chandrasekar/#comment-353737), when this same question was asked:  "the Goals should be either removed due to their vapid collective appeal or modified to actually qualify or quantify what being diverse, inclusive, and welcoming means." (with further thoughts/examples in that comment)

Comment: We shouldn't forget it was caused by the reaction to [a single tweet by an external party](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52), bypassing the inefficient meta process.

Comment: Regarding your wish in your last line: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'd disagree. There have been many attempts to do this *under different names* so far in the past like the summer of love. This is *absolutely* nothing new. While I sometimes feel that outsiders wanting to change fundamental things with no desire to engage does more harm than good - in this case these goals are something SE *has* been trying to reach, for a long while with mixed effects.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect this is kinda the wrong question.

I guess the right question is "How much closer have we come to those goals, and what are the results of our efforts?"

*The journey is as important as the destination*.

It's 'easy' to talk about 'diversity' and 'inclusiveness' and 'welcoming' in broad strokes, or to make great big plans. The results matter, and hopefully we'll see someone talking about success stories as much as plans ;)

Answer (score 4):

## There's no indication anywhere that SO planned on only focusing on these topics for only one year

I can't find any place where SO has explicitly laid out their goals for a specific year. Even the post you posit as being the goals for 2018 says nothing of the sort. The fact that it outlines  a new policy initiative for the company and came out in 2018 does not in any way imply that the company thought that these would be the goals only for 2018 and they would be dropped as soon as the calendar ticked over.

In fact, [the article on being welcoming](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) goes to lengths to stress how long these have been goals and how important they are going forward:

> **Caring about this isn’t new to us**. Initiatives like the [Summer of Love](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/), the [closing overhaul](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/06/25/the-war-of-the-closes/), [revising the “Be Nice” Policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback), and our [coaching experiment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up?noredirect=1&lq=1) all came from our desire to build a place where everyone feels welcome.

This quote references initiatives showing the company was trying to  focus on issues like the ones mentioned as goals for this year all the way back in 2012.

SO thinks it is important for it to focus on being more diverse, inclusive, and welcoming, but it seems pretty clear that this is a long-term focus for them not tied to any year.

Your implication that focusing on the same issue for more than one year is bad or surprising at all is kind of baffling to me. If something is a problem that you want to tackle and it can't/isn't solved in one year, why wouldn't you make it a goal for the next year as well? Isn't that the expected behavior?

And honestly, they would be foolish to have thought that they could tackle hate and rudeness on the internet in one year. That fight is never going to stop.

So, to answer you question directly, yes it does seem very similar to themes espoused in the past, but all that means is that the company is continuing to focus on these issues.

Comment: As always, I encourage downvoters to let me know if there is anything I can do to improve this post. Did I miss something?

Comment: Its just a controversial issue. These things happen :/